# Find a multiple of a given number whose decimal representation looks like binary

Tags: code-golf, number

I have come across a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/107221) on the Code Review site that seems interesting. I think OP is doing it wrong, but cannot be sure... So let's solve it for him! (write a program, not a function/procedure)

### Input (stdin or similar):

An integer `x` in decimal notation. It is greater than 1 and less than 2^31.

### Output (stdout or similar):

An integer `y` in decimal notation. The product `x * y` in decimal representation must contain only digits 0 and 1. It must be the minimal such number greater than 0.

Note: output is not limited - if the minimal `y` is around 10^100, your program must output all of its 100 digits (I don't know whether there is a reasonable limit, like 2^64, on `y` - didn't solve it).

Your program should finish in a reasonable time (1 second? 1 hour? - something like that) for all `x` in range.

#### Bonus:

If your program doesn't have a limit on the size of the input (except RAM), and has polynomial complexity, multiply the byte count of your program by `0.8` and round down.

---

Example: Input `2`; output `5`, because 2 * 5 = 10

Example: Input `21`; output `481`, because 21 * 481 = 10101

---

Disclaimer: I am not responsible for the question on the Code Review site. In case of any discrepancy, only the description above should be regarded as proper spec.

[**OEIS A079339**](http://oeis.org/A079339)

Comment: It should always be solvable. Clearly there must exist at least one q such that there are an infinite number of n such that 10^n mod x = q. Take x such values of n and add together the respective powers 10^n.

Comment: Multiples of 9 seem to produce unusually high results.

Comment: [Related Project Euler problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=303), for anyone else who thought this question looked familiar

Comment: By polynomial complexity, do you mean polynomial in the number of digits of the input, or polynomial in the value of the input?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Polynomial in the number of digits, of course! Otherwise, you cannot run it => no fun.

Comment: `input();print 0` - you should probably limit `y` to > 0 ;)

Comment: @SuperJedi224 well, you need at least 9 `1`'s to get a multiple of 9

Comment: I guess I was too optimistic about complexity, and it's impossible to make it polynomial on the size of input - the size of the output seems to be exponential on input. But hey - all the 16 answers so far are brute-force?! Surely you can do better!

Comment: Umm... there is _always_ a value that can be resolved that looks like binary (circumventing the output 0 rule), simply because there is an infinite range of numbers.

Comment: @anatolyg mine is not brute force

Comment: @primo re bounty: time to calc or time to print in console? Maybe redirect to file

Comment: @edc65 Output must be generated, although for timing it will be discarded (i.e. piped to `/dev/null`. I will however check it for accuracy). You may optimize your solution to produce each value sequentially, if that helps. If you prefer to be timed with a specific interpreter/compiler, please specify.

Comment: @primo, how special-cased can the fast code be? E.g. can it restrict to using narrower int types which wouldn't be sufficient for input `99999999`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor if it produces the correct output for all values between 1-10000, I will consider it valid. I will be evaluating all solutions shortly.

Comment: I've a proof that the length of the output is indeed at most linear in the size of the input (and thus exponential in the length of the input), but it cannot fit in a comment box. It relies on two ideas: 1) That for any N, 10^i % N has a period with length <= N - 1 or has finite support, and 2) There exists a multiple of N that equals a linear combination of numbers less than N such that their coefficients sum to at most N.

Comment: The Bounty was awarded to [aditsu's c answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61905). Final scoreboard: http://codepad.org/DVRGITHP (average of 5 runs). I didn't test any "count by one" solutions, so if I've missed yours, and it's faster than aditsu's c, I'll double down on the bounty.

Comment: I'm like 95% certain that the length of the output is linear in the length of the input; I'm trying to find an existence proof and possibly a constructive proof if I can get that far.

Comment: @Candles If you can prove that the worst case is repeated 9's (empirically correct up to quite a few repeated 9's), there's your constructive proof.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 multiples of mine that fit this answer will be at minimum 111111111, because any number x where x % 9 = 0, the numbers added up recursively will equal 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 8 bytes

```
fq`;{`*Q
```

**[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fq%60%3B%7B%60%2aQ&input=21&debug=0)**

---

## How?

```
fq`;{`*Q   - Full program.

f          - First input where the condition is truthy over [1, ∞)
      *Q   - The product of the input and the current number
     `     - Converted to String.
    {      - Deduplicated.
 q         - Is equal to?
  `;       - The string representation of the innermost lambda variable, T, which is "10".
           - Output implicitly.
```

This pretty much relies on the fact that numbers do not have trailing zeros, and `1` always occurs before `0` in a positive integer only consisting of `0`s and `1`s.

Answer (score 20):

## Python 2, efficient solution, 99

```py
n=input()
d={n:0}
k=1
while min(d):[d.setdefault((x+k)%n,d[x]+k)for x in set(d)];k*=10
print d[0]/n
```

Thanks Sp3000 for some golfing tips.

I challenge everybody else to post (in their own answers) how long it takes to get the result for input `72` or `99` :) If those are really fast, try something like `79992` next (still <1 sec here).

**Explanation:**

I thought this wasn't necessary (since the code is fairly readable), but I got a request, so here it goes:

The first idea is that a binary-looking number is a sum of 1 or more different powers of 10. Therefore, we can try to add various powers of 10 in different ways until we get remainder 0.

If we do that naively, it's the same as generating all binary-looking numbers and testing them. But a lot of remainders will be the same. A better way is to record only the smallest number that gave a certain remainder, and successively add greater powers of 10 to numbers we recorded. That's what the program does.

`d` is a dictionary/map where keys are remainders and values are binary-looking numbers with that remainder. The initial `n:0` is a special case: it's supposed to be `0:0` so we can start adding powers to it, but the algorithm stops when finding key 0, so I used `n` instead, which is guaranteed to have the same effect and not interfere with the other values.

Then we start adding powers of 10 (stored in `k`) to all existing numbers and recording the remainders. We add `k` to the remainder: `(x+k)%n` and to the number: `d[x]+k`, and record it only if it's a new remainder: `d.setdefault(…)`, then go to the next power: `k*=10` and repeat until we get key 0: `while min(d)`

At the end, `d[0]` gives the binary-looking number that has remainder 0 mod `n`, so we divide it by `n` to get the solution.

Note: the program can be made more efficient by avoiding large numbers (recording exponents rather than powers of 10, and calculating remainders of powers from previous values), but it's code golf, so...

In fact, here, I wrote a faster version:

```py
n=input()
d={n:0}
k=1
b=0
while 0not in d:
 for x in list(d):d.setdefault((x+k)%n,b)
 k=(k*10)%n;b+=1
x=10**d[0]
while x%n:x+=10**d[n-x%n]
print x/n
```

Comment: My answer doesn't get either. xD "Dangit, Java, curse thy choice of Integer.MAX_VALUE over using BigInteger by default!" - Every Java Programmer Ever

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE why don't you use Long?

Comment: Hmm. It's an extra byte, but... worth it. Thanks!

Comment: Or not. That actually seriously reduces it. Thanks!

Comment: 72, 99 and some more in ~370 millisec http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61051/21348

Comment: Timings for solving 99: aditsu: 0.001 seconds; xnor: 5+ hours and it still didn't complete.

Comment: @aditsu challenge accepted!, well almost :) [72 = ~0.007 s, 99 = ~0.45s] http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61076/46177

Comment: You can get a speed-up of about 30% with some basic number theory. If `ntlog(b, x)` gives the greatest `a` such that `x % (b**a) == 0` then start `k` at `10**max(ntlog(2,n), ntlog(5,n))`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor what's ntlog?

Comment: Read the first half of that sentence again

Comment: @PeterTaylor is it just a weird name you gave to an ad-hoc function?

Comment: I have a vague memory of seeing it called the *number-theoretic logarithm to base b* somewhere, but I can't find a reference.

Answer (score 12):

## Javascript, 43 bytes

This ended up way shorter than I thought. It basically increments `y` up 1 until `y * (input number) = (binary-looking number)`. Obviously quite inefficient.

```js
for(x=prompt(y=0);!+('0b'+x*++y););alert(y)
```

---

## Javascript (more efficient solution), 53 bytes

This one increments `y` in binary until `y / (input number) = (number without a remainder)`. Then it outputs `(number without a remainder)`.

```js
for(x=prompt(y=1);(z=y.toString(2))%x;y++);alert(z/x)
```

---

## Javascript (even more efficient solution), 76 bytes

This one combines both of the previous methods described above. It checks increments `y` until either `y * (input number) = (binary-looking number)` (meaning that the output is `y`) OR `y / (input number) = (number without a remainder)` (meaning that the output is `(number without a remainder)`).

```js
for(x=prompt(y=a=0);!a;a=+('0b'+x*++y)?y:(z=y.toString(2))%x?0:z/x);alert(a)
```

Comment: It should give 1 when possible (example input: 1)

Comment: @edc65 Fixed - with no change in byte count!

Comment: This crashes Safari 9.0. Jussayin'. :)

Comment: But it's limited to small numbers in output. Javascript numbers have 17 digits of precision, OP is asking for something bigger (and it can be done using modular arithmetic)

Comment: Protip: Don't try input 72. Firefox 41 freezes up for 15 minutes and then crashes. I discovered this the hard way.

Comment: I added a more efficient solution, so no more crashes (I hope).

Answer (score 12):

### Python 2, 47 bytes

```python
n=a=input()
while'1'<max(str(a)):a+=n
print a/n
```

Tracks the input number `n` and the current multiple `a`. When `a` looks like binary, output the ratio `a/n`. To check that a number is made of `0`'s and `1`'s, we compare the maximum char in its string representation to `'1'`.

Uses `str(a)` instead of `` `a` `` to avoid longs ending in `L`. Unfortunately, `'L'` is bigger than `'1'`.

Answer (score 12):

## Perl, 27 bytes

```perl
#!perl -p
1while($_*++$\)=~/[2-9]/}{
```

Counting the shebang as one, input is taken from stdin.

**Sample Usage**

```perl
$ echo 2 | perl dec-bin.pl
5

$ echo 21 | perl dec-bin.pl
481

$ echo 98 | perl dec-bin.pl
112245
```

---

## Perl, 25 bytes

```perl
#!perl -p
eval'0b'.++$\*$_||redo}{
```

A two byte improvement by [@skmrx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60942/60981#comment146985_60981).

Rather than checking against a regex, this instead attempts to evaluate the product as a binary literal. Upon failure, it moves on to the next. Typically the `oct` function would be used for this purpose, but it silently trims invalid digits, which isn't useful in this challenge.

---

## Perl, 40 bytes

```perl
#!perl -p
1while($b=sprintf"%b",++$i)%$_;$_=$b/$_
```

A far more efficient solution. We iterate over binary representations, interpret them as base 10, and then check for divisibility. Runtimes for all values under 100 are negligible.

**Sample Usage**

```perl
$ echo 72|perl dec-bin.pl
1543209875

$ echo 99|perl dec-bin.pl
1122334455667789
```

Comment: Nice :) I learnt a couple of  new things from your post today! While reading through your code, I found a way to shave off a couple of bytes from the first code:
`eval"0b".$_*++$\||redo}{`

Comment: But I guess we'll need to include `use bigint` to support the large numbers that OP has mandated to be supported :(

Comment: @skmrn That's brilliant. I had tried `oct'0b'.++$\*$_`, but it silently trims invalid digits. I didn't think to use `eval` instead.

Answer (score 9):

## Haskell, <s>72</s> <s>70</s> <s>64</s> <s>60</s> 58 bytes

```
main=do x<-readLn;print$[y|y<-[1..],all(<'2')$show$x*y]!!0
```

Edit: @Jan Dvorak helped me saving 4 bytes.

Edit: @BlackCap saved 2 bytes by switching to `do` notation. Thanks!

Comment: `main=print.f=<<readLn`

Comment: You can save a byte by inlining f: `main=readLn>>= \x->print$[y|y<-[1..],all(<'2')$show$x*y]!!0`

Comment: 2 actually `main=do x<-readLn;print$[y|y<-[1..],all(<'2')$show$x*y]!!0`

Comment: @BlackCap: Nice! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
f!-`*TQ10
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%21-%60%2aTQ10&input=21&debug=0)

For each multiple, convert to a string, subtract out the digits in `10` (using Pyth's handy int to str cast in this case) and then logically negate the result, terminating the seach only when the correct multiple is found.

#### Bonus solution, 10 bytes:

```
f.xi`*TQ2Z
```

This solution actually checks if the string representation of the number can be treated as a binary number (`i ... 2`) and terminates when an error is not thrown on this attempt.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, <s>67</s> <s>65</s> <s>63</s> 60 bytes

```
a=input();b=1
while set(`a*b`)&set('23456789'):b+=1
print b
```

Thanks to [Status](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34315/status) for 2 bytes and [Shebang](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38417/shebang) for 5 bytes!

Comment: I think you must initialize `b=1`

Comment: Corrected, @anatolyg.

Comment: You can shave 2 bytes by doing ``any(c in`a*b`for c in'23456789')``

Comment: Excellent, @Status, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but would `not c in\`a*b\`for c in'10'` work?

Comment: Alas, syntax error, @Cole. It feels like you're onto something good, though.

Comment: You can save 6 bytes by changing your while condition to `set('a*b')&set('23456789')`.

Comment: Implemented your suggestion @ThomasKwa, thanks!

Comment: `\`` produces an `L` for longs and `'L'>'1'`.

Comment: As @Clearquestionwithexamples said, this wont work for `x*y > 2147483647`.

Comment: Thanks @Clearquestionwithexamples; I've updated the answer with your solution.

Comment: @mbomb007 Now that he's changed to the set thing, he can use backticks.

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but it's close enough I'll just share the improvement. `while set(str(n*i))-{"1","0"}` or `while set(str(n*i))-set("01")` is shorter by 4 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6) 222 <s>250</s>

Using arbitrary precision math (operating on strings of decimal digits)

<s>This can be golfed a little more</s>(done), but I like the fact that it is not limited to JS standard numbers (17 decimal digits of precision) and that it is fast.

Test running the snippet below in an EcmaScript 6 compliant browser. Time is acceptable up to 9998 - don't try 9999 and be patient with 999.

```js
// As a complete program with I/O via popup  
for(n=+prompt(a=[0],q=[t=1]);t;){for(c=1,t=i=0;i<a.length;i++)a[i]=a[i]&c?0:a[i]|c?(c=0,t+=q[i],1):c=0;c&&(a[i]=c,t+=q[i]=q[i-1]*10%n);t%=n}a.reverse().map(a=>(z+=[a],d=z/n|0,z%=n,r||d?r+=d:0),r='',z=0);alert([r,a.join``])

// As a testable function
f=n=>{
  for(a=[0],q=[t=1];t;)
  {
    for(c=1,t=i=0;i<a.length;i++)
      a[i]=a[i]&c?0:a[i]|c?(c=0,t+=q[i],1):c=0
    c&&(a[i]=c,t+=q[i]=q[i-1]*10%n);
    t%=n
  }  
  a.reverse().map(a=>(z+=[a],d=z/n|0,z%=n,r||d?r+=d:0),r='',z=0)
  return [r,a.join``]
}

// Test and timing
out = x => O.innerHTML += x + '\n'

setTimeout(_=>{
;[1,2,10, 21, 23, 98, 72, 9, 99, 999]
.forEach((test,i) => { 
  var t0 = ~new Date  
  var result = f(test)
  out('n='+test+' '+result+' time(ms) ' + (t0-~new Date))
})},100)
```

```html
<pre id=O>Timing test cases ...
</pre>
```

**More readable**

This is the first version, with modulus and long division as separated functions.

```js
// function M - Modulus with arbitrary precision - a is a string of decimal digits
M = (a, b, q = 1, t = 0, j = a.length) => {
  while (j--) + a[j] ? t += q : 0, q = (q * 10) % b;
  return t % b
}

// function D - Long division with arbitrary precision - a is a string of decimal digits
D = (a, b, r = '', z = 0) => [...a].map(a => (z += a, d = z / b | 0, z %= b, r || d ? r += d : 0)) && r

// Testable function 
f = n => {
  for (i = 0; ++i < 1e7 && (z = M(v = i.toString(2), n)););
  return z ? ['big'] : [D(v, n), v]
}
```

Comment: I got it to work in Firefox, but it doesn't seem handle bigger numbers, e.g. 999

Comment: I'have a new version that can handle 999 in 36 seconds, but there's no hope to reach 9999 with the javascript timeout (each '9' added require 2^9 (~500) times the time to finish)

Comment: @aditsu that's the best I can do in JavaScript (but in C# it's quite the same). Eaherly waiting for an explanation of you incredible algorithm

Comment: I added an explanation now

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, 45 bytes

```
do{$a++}while($a*($b||=<>))=~/[2-9]/;print$a;
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python <s>3</s> 2, <s>101</s> 76 Bytes

**-25** bytes thanks to @aditsu

almost as efficient as @aditsu's solution

```
99 -> 0.436 Seconds
72 -> 0.007 Seconds
```

```pyton
b,m,n=1,1,input()
while b%n:
 b=int("{0:b}".format(m))
 m+=1
print b/n
```

Instead of trying to loop through the multiples in increasing order, I'm trying to loop through the products, which I'm generating in 'binary' form.

Comment: Not bad :) What about 9999?

Comment: Some golfing tips: use python 2 (`n=input()`), `while b%n:` (initialize `b` to 1), no indentation

Comment: @aditsu Thanks!  9999 hmmm, looks like it'll take a couple of days, well back to the drawing board -_-

Comment: `bin(m)[2:]` should be shorter than the format string. Double assignment on `b=m=1` should save a few as well.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, 213 bytes

```
import java.math.*;class P{public static void main(String[]a){BigInteger b=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextBigInteger(),c,d=c=b.ONE;while(!(b.multiply(c)+"").matches("[01]+"))c=c.add(d);System.out.print(c);}}
```

Uses `BigInteger`s and as such has (for all reasonable intents and purposes) unbounded input size. Not sure about the complexity though, that depends on the growth rate of our function here.

Thanks to geobits and ypnypn for saving a handful of bytes.

Comment: Hi, how would you call this in your main method please? Trying it but not succeeding

Comment: You'd have to add the `static` modifier to the method.

Comment: The question says that the solution should be a complete program, not just a function.

Comment: You can cut 15 with `b.ONE` and `!(b.multiply(c)+"")` (instead of `toString()`).

Comment: @raznagul: Fixed.

Comment: You can replace `println` with `print`

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
li:V!{)_V*sAs-}g
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=li%3AV!%7B)_V*sAs-%7Dg&input=21)

Brute force solution, trying values sequentially until one meeting the condition is found.

The latest version saves 2 bytes thanks to using `As` instead of `"01"` to build a string containing `0` and `1`, as suggested by @aditsu. The full proposed solution in the comment saves another byte, but it looks fairly different from mine, so I didn't want to post it under my name.

And 1 more byte saved by @Dennis.

Explanation:

```
li      Get input and convert to int.
:V      Save it in variable V.
!       Negate the value. Since we saved it in V, we don't need it on the stack anymore.
        But we need 0 on the stack as the start value for y. This conveniently
        accomplishes both with a single operator, since the input is guaranteed to be
        larger than 0.
{       Loop over y.
  )       Increment y.
  _       Copy it.
  V*      Multiply with input in variable V.
  s       Convert to string.
  As      Push the string "10", as the number 10 converted to a string .
  -       Remove 0 and 1 digits. This will result in an empty list if there were only
          0 and 1 digits. The empty list is falsy, and will terminate the loop.
}g      End loop.
```

Comment: 16: `li0{1$+_sAs-}g\/`

Comment: Thanks, @aditsu. I didn't really want to copy your full solution under my name. I did take the `As` to build the string, since it's a very local change, which in hindsight (which is always much easier...) I should have thought of.

Comment: @RetoKoradi 16 bytes, less modifications: `li:V!{)_V*sAs-}g` Also, `0{)_easi*sAs-}g` (15 bytes) works with the Java interpreter and command-line arguments.

Answer (score 4):

### Pyth, 10 bytes

```
f<eS`*TQ`2
```

[Run the code.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%3CeS%60%2ATQ%602&input=21&debug=0)

A port of my [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60975/20260), taking from [Maltysen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60971/20260) the use of `f` to find the first positive number that meets a condition.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 50 bytes

```
while(preg_match('/[^01]/',$argv[1]*++$y));echo$y;
```

**Some test cases**

```
1 > 1
2 > 5
12 > 925
21 > 481
```

Comment: Was gonna make something like this, this is even a tad shorter than I had in mind

Answer (score 4):

## C++11, many bytes, very fast, wow (1.5 s on 1999999998, 0.2 s on 1…10000)

(Golfed Python version below.)

We start with a concept somewhat similar to aditsu’s solution, where we inductively build up a collection of modular remainders reachable in n steps.  But instead of waiting until we find remainder 0, we check for two found remainders a and b such that a·10^n + b = 0.  This meet-in-the-middle approach halves the depth of the search tree, so it’s much faster on large inputs and uses much less memory.

Some benchmarks:

```
$ echo 99999999 | \time ./decbin
1111111122222222333333334444444455555555666666667777777788888889
0.18user 0.01system 0:00.20elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 69360maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+16276minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ echo 999999999 | \time ./decbin
111111111222222222333333333444444444555555555666666666777777777888888889
1.22user 0.04system 0:01.27elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 434776maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+37308minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ echo 2147483647 | \time ./decbin
4661316525084584315813
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.01elapsed 72%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5960maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1084minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ echo 1999999998 | \time ./decbin
555555556111111111666666667222222222777777778333333333888888889444444445
1.42user 0.08system 0:01.50elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 544140maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+38379minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ \time ./decbin 10000.out
0.19user 0.00system 0:00.20elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3324maxresident)k
0inputs+264outputs (0major+160minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

static inline bool cmp_first_partnered(pair<int, pair<int, int>> a,
                                       pair<int, pair<int, int>> b) {
  return a.first < b.first;
}
static inline bool eq_first_partnered(pair<int, pair<int, int>> a,
                                      pair<int, pair<int, int>> b) {
  return a.first == b.first;
}

static pair<int, int> retrace(int modulus, int place, pair<int, int> state,
                              list<vector<int>>::iterator i,
                              list<vector<int>>::iterator j, string &ret) {
  if (i == j)
    return state;
  state = retrace(modulus, (place * 10LL) % modulus, state, next(i), j, ret);
  int remainder = state.first;
  long long k = state.second * 10LL;
  if (!binary_search(i->cbegin(), i->cend(), remainder)) {
    remainder = ((long long)remainder + modulus - place) % modulus;
    k += 1;
  }
  int digit = k / modulus;
  if (digit != 0 || ret.size())
    ret += '0' + digit;
  return make_pair(remainder, k % modulus);
}

static void mult(int modulus, int x, int y,
                 vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>>::iterator i,
                 vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>>::iterator j) {
  if (y - x == 1) {
    for (auto k = i; k != j; k++)
      k->first = (k->first * 10LL) % modulus;
    return;
  }

  int z = (x + y) / 2;
  vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>>::iterator k = lower_bound(
      i, j, make_pair(int(((long long)modulus * z + 9) / 10), make_pair(0, 0)));
  mult(modulus, x, z, i, k);
  mult(modulus, z, y, k, j);
  inplace_merge(i, k, j,
                [](pair<int, pair<int, int>> a, pair<int, pair<int, int>> b) {
                  return make_pair(a.first, a.second.second) <
                         make_pair(b.first, b.second.second);
                });
}

static string go(int modulus) {
  if (modulus == 1)
    return "1";

  int sequence = 1;
  list<vector<int>> v = {{0}};
  vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>> partnered;
  int place = 1;
  while (true) {
    v.emplace_back(v.rbegin()->size() * 2);
    vector<int> &previous = *next(v.rbegin()), &current = *v.rbegin();

    auto offset = [modulus, place, sequence](int a) {
      return (a + (long long)place) % modulus;
    };
    auto old_mid =
        lower_bound(previous.cbegin(), previous.cend(), modulus - place),
         new_mid = lower_bound(previous.cbegin(), previous.cend(), place);
    current.resize(
        set_union(new_mid, previous.cend(),
                  make_transform_iterator(previous.cbegin(), offset),
                  make_transform_iterator(old_mid, offset),
                  set_union(previous.cbegin(), new_mid,
                            make_transform_iterator(old_mid, offset),
                            make_transform_iterator(previous.cend(), offset),
                            current.begin())) -
        current.begin());

    int place2 = modulus - (long long)place * place % modulus;
    auto offset_partnered = [modulus, place, place2,
                             sequence](pair<int, pair<int, int>> a) {
      return make_pair((a.first + (long long)place2) % modulus,
                       make_pair((a.second.first + (long long)place) % modulus,
                                 sequence + a.second.second));
    };
    auto old_mid_partnered =
        lower_bound(partnered.cbegin(), partnered.cend(),
                    make_pair(modulus - place2, make_pair(0, 0))),
         new_mid_partnered = lower_bound(partnered.cbegin(), partnered.cend(),
                                         make_pair(place2, make_pair(0, 0)));
    vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>> next_partnered(partnered.size() * 2 + 1);
    auto i =
        set_union(partnered.cbegin(), new_mid_partnered,
                  make_transform_iterator(old_mid_partnered, offset_partnered),
                  make_transform_iterator(partnered.cend(), offset_partnered),
                  next_partnered.begin(), cmp_first_partnered);
    if (new_mid_partnered == partnered.cend() ||
        new_mid_partnered->first != place2)
      *i++ = make_pair(place2, make_pair(place, sequence));
    next_partnered.resize(
        set_union(new_mid_partnered, partnered.cend(),
                  make_transform_iterator(partnered.cbegin(), offset_partnered),
                  make_transform_iterator(old_mid_partnered, offset_partnered),
                  i, cmp_first_partnered) -
        next_partnered.begin());
    partnered.swap(next_partnered);

    sequence += previous.size();

    place = (place * 10LL) % modulus;

    mult(modulus, 0, 10, partnered.begin(), partnered.end());
    partnered.resize(
        unique(partnered.begin(), partnered.end(), eq_first_partnered) -
        partnered.begin());

    auto with_first = [](int a) { return make_pair(a, make_pair(a, 0)); };

    vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>> hits;
    set_intersection(partnered.cbegin(), partnered.cend(),
                     make_transform_iterator(current.cbegin(), with_first),
                     make_transform_iterator(current.cend(), with_first),
                     back_inserter(hits), cmp_first_partnered);

    if (hits.size()) {
      pair<int, pair<int, int>> best = *min_element(
          hits.begin(), hits.end(),
          [](pair<int, pair<int, int>> a, pair<int, pair<int, int>> b) {
            return a.second.second < b.second.second;
          });
      string ret = "";
      pair<int, int> state =
          retrace(modulus, 1, make_pair(best.second.first, 0), v.begin(),
                  prev(v.end()), ret);
      retrace(modulus, 1, make_pair(best.first, state.second), v.begin(),
              prev(v.end()), ret);
      return ret;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  if (argc >= 2) {
    ofstream ofs(argv[1]);
    for (int modulus = 1; modulus <= 10000; modulus++)
      ofs << go(modulus) << '\n';
  } else {
    int modulus;
    cin >> modulus;
    cout << go(modulus) << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

## Python, 280 bytes (8.6 seconds on 1999999998 with PyPy)

```
n=input()
if n<2:print 1;exit()
d={0:0}
l=[]
k=1
b=x=y=0
while 1:
 for a in[0]+l:
  m=(a+k)%n
  if m not in d:l.append(m);d[m]=b
 k=(k*10)%n;b+=1
 for a in l:
  if(-k*a)%n in d:
   while(a-x)%n:x+=10**d[(a-x)%n]
   while(-y-k*a)%n:y+=10**d[(-y-k*a)%n]
   print(10**b*x+y)/n;exit()
```

Comment: I understand that you're after the bounty, but even so this is a [tag:code-golf] question, and the site rules require you to make *some* effort to golf your code.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, very well, I added a golfed version in Python.

Comment: [1648 bytes](https://ideone.com/BwqPFe)

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 115 bytes

```
p=Drop[Union[FromDigits/@Flatten[Table[Tuples[{0,1},{k}],{k,2,12}],1]],2];
i=Input[];FirstCase[p,x_/;Divisible[x,i]]
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, 45 bytes

```
x=scan();y=2;while(grepl("[2-9]",x*y))y=y+1;y
```

Usage:

```
> x=scan();y=2;while(grepl("[2-9]",x*y))y=y+1;y
1: 2
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 5
> x=scan();y=2;while(grepl("[2-9]",x*y))y=y+1;y
1: 21
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 481
> x=scan();y=2;while(grepl("[2-9]",x*y))y=y+1;y
1: 42
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 2405
```

Answer (score 3):

**Java 156 bytes**

```
public class P{public static void main(String[]a){long x=Long.valueOf(a[0]),y;for(y=2;!(""+x*y).replaceAll("1|0","").isEmpty();y++);System.out.println(y);}}
```

Massive thanks to aditsu :)

Comment: You don't need a space after `[]`, `y` can be `long` too, you forgot the `x*y+""` trick in the 2nd program, use `isEmpty` instead of checking the length, use `;` instead of `{}`

Comment: Anyway, welcome to code golf :)

Comment: I must say, I am impressed, but making y `long` wouldn't make the code shorter

Comment: Yes it would: `long x=…,y;`

Comment: `y` must start from 1, you can initialize it in the declaration, your class doesn't need to be public, and you can move `y++` to the `x*y` part (`x*y++`)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Uses filter with numeric arg to get first natural number that fulfills predicate, default is 1 which is what we want. Setwise diff to check if only zeros and ones.

```
f!-j*QT10U2
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%21-j%2aQT10U2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A21&debug=0).

Comment: Convert to string and remove `"01`. Saves one char.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>198</s> <s>193</s> 181 bytes

Thanks to @aditsu for shaving off 5 bytes AND increasing the range of testable numbers!

Note that some values loop negatively due to how Java parses integers. This could be circumvented by BigInteger, but the bonus was simply less valuable.

I know that I'm not going to win, but I hope this inspires other, shorter, answers.

```
class A{public static void main(String[] a){for(long i=1;;i++){try{long b=Long.parseLong(a[0]);if(b*i<0)break;Long.parseLong(b*i+"",2);System.out.println(i);}catch(Exception e){}}}}
```

Ungofled:

```
class A {
   public static void main(String[] a){
      for(long i=1;;i++){ // infinite loop starting at 1
         try{ // if an error is thrown by attempting to parse as binary, restart while adding 1 to i
            long b=Long.parseLong(a[0]); // For later - it was shorter to declare than use twice
            if(b*i<0)break; // Break out of the program if we have looped.
            Long.parseLong(b*i+"",2); // Multiply out and see if it's passable as a binary number, otherwise, throw error and go back to the top of the loop
            System.out.println(b); // print it out
         } catch (Exception e) {} // do nothing on catch
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's funny that `Long` is shorter than `Integer` :)

Comment: The most _literal_ irony there is.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <strike>107</strike> 101 bytes (<strike>105</strike> 99 bytes for 32-bits)

There is a distinct lack of answers in C on code golf. Indeed, C is not the best choice for writing the smallest possible program, but it's not that bad:

```
main(d,b){char s[9];gets(s);for(b=atoi(s);sprintf(s,"%d",b*d),strspn(s,"01")[s];d++);printf("%d",d);}
```

You can do without the #includes, but then all the function definitions will be implicit. The main drawback is that this causes the assumption that all functions return ints. This is a problem on 64-bit machines for functions that actually return a pointer. If you are on a 32-bit machine, 2 bytes can be shaved off the above solution:

```
main(d,b){char s[9];for(b=atoi(gets(s));sprintf(s,"%d",b*d),strspn(s,"01")[s];d++);printf("%d",d);}
```

Somewhat more readable version:

```
int main()
{
  char s[9];
  gets(s);
  int d = 1;
  int b = atoi(s);
  for (; sprintf(s, "%d", b * d), strspn(s, "01")[s]; d++);
  printf("%d", d);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C# time near 5 seconds (1 to 10000)

As requested, here is a golfed C# program answering the original challenge.
Input as command line argument, output to console.

```cs
using System;using System.Collections.Generic;using System.Numerics;using System.Linq;
class P{static void Main(string[] a){int m,n=int.Parse(a[0]);var d=new Dictionary<int,long>();long b;int h;
for(d[n]=0,b=h=1;;b*=2,h=(h*10)%n)foreach(int k in d.Keys.Reverse())if(!d.ContainsKey(m=(h+k)%n)){
var w=d[k]|b;if(m==0){Console.Write(BigInteger.Parse(Convert.ToString(w,2))/n);return;}d.Add(m,w);}}}
```

Then, as for the bounty: the bounty should go to aditsu, as I think his algorithm cannot be beaten in terms of perfomance. But anatolyg self-answer is amazing too.

Here is my fast implementation in C#. I suppose that in C++ it could be faster (maybe 2x). Compiled and tested with Visual Studio 2010, .NET framework 4, 64 bits, redirecting output to nul. Time : 00:00:05.2604315

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
   static BigInteger Find(int n)
   {
      var d = new Dictionary<int, long>();
      long kb;
      int km;
      d[n] = 0;
      for (kb = km = 1; ; kb *= 2, km = (km * 10) % n)
      {
         foreach (int key in d.Keys.Reverse())
         {
            int m = (km + key) % n;
            if (!d.ContainsKey(m))
            {
               long w = d[key] | kb;
               if (m == 0)
               {
                  return BigInteger.Parse(Convert.ToString(w, 2));
               }
               d.Add(m, w);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   static void Exec(int n, out string sq, out string sa)
   {
      var v = Find(n);
      sq = (v/n).ToString();
      sa = v.ToString();
   }  

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      // string n = Console.ReadLine();
      int limit = int.Parse(args[0]);
      string q ="", a = "";
      Stopwatch x = new Stopwatch();
      x.Start();
      for (int n = 1; n <= limit; n++)
      {
         Exec(n, out q, out a);
         Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", n, q, a);
      }
      x.Stop();
      Console.Error.WriteLine("{0}", x.Elapsed);
   }
}
```

Comment: Times 4.1s. I misspoke in the bounty. With the latest version of PyPy, aditsu's faster version times approximately 8s, so this is twice as fast.

Comment: I understand that you're after the bounty, but even so this is a [tag:code-golf] question, and the site rules require you to make *some* effort to golf your code.

Comment: I'm not after the bounty, it's just an example of implementation. But you're right, I'll add a golfed version.

Comment: @PeterTaylor could it go now?

Comment: By the way, why `Keys.Reverse`? Is the order important? If it's just to avoid concurrency issues, `ToList` is shorter.

Comment: @PeterTaylor yes `ToList` is ok (but I'm not sure why, `Reverse` seems faster)

Answer (score 2):

### C with GMP (621 bytes, fast)

I've tried to be fast and short, but favoured fast. This implementation uses a slightly improved version of the number-theoretic speedup I mentioned in a comment on [aditsu's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61003/194).

Save as `pseudobinary.c` and compile with `gcc pseudobinary.c -lgmp -o pseudobinary`. Note that this allocates so much memory for large inputs that you will need to compile it for a 64-bit platform.

```c
#include <gmp.h>
int main(int y,char*z[]){int i,n,b,c,e,f,m,*j,*k,*l,*r,*h;char *d,*s;mpz_t
B,I,Q;i=atoi(z[1]);n=i;for(b=0;n%10<1;++b)n/=10;for(;n%2<1;++b)n/=2;for(;n%5<1;++b)n/=5;if(n<2)--b;d=calloc(n,1);j=calloc(n,sizeof(int));r=calloc(99,sizeof(int));c=2;d[1]=1;*j=r[1]=e=1;l=j+1;for(s=0;!s;++c){r[c]=e=e*10%n;k=l;for(h=j;h<k;h++){f=*h;m=(e+f)%n;if(d[m]<1){*l++=m;if(m<1){s=malloc(99);memset(s,48,99);for(f=c;f;f=d[m=(m+n-r[f])%n])s[c-f]++;s[c]=0;h=k;}d[m]=c;}}}f=strlen(s);s[f]=48;s[f+b]=0;mpz_init_set_str(B,s,10);mpz_init_set_si(I,i);mpz_init(Q);mpz_divexact(Q,B,I);d=mpz_get_str(0,10,Q);printf("%s\n",d);return 0;}
```

#### Loop version for timing (751 bytes)

```c
#include <gmp.h>
char **v;int main(){int i,n,b,c,e,f,m,*j,*k,*l,*r,*h;char *d,*s;mpz_t
B,I,Q;v=calloc(10001,sizeof(char*));v[1]=s=malloc(99);memset(s,48,99);*s=49;s[1]=0;for(i=0;++i<10001;){n=i;for(b=0;n%10<1;++b)n/=10;for(;n%2<1;++b)n/=2;for(;n%5<1;++b)n/=5;d=calloc(n,1);j=calloc(n,sizeof(int));r=calloc(99,sizeof(int));c=2;d[1]=1;*j=r[1]=e=1;l=j+1;for(;!v[n];++c){r[c]=e=e*10%n;k=l;for(h=j;h<k;h++){f=*h;m=(e+f)%n;if(d[m]<1){*l++=m;if(m<1){v[n]=s=malloc(99);memset(s,48,99);for(f=c;f;f=d[m=(m+n-r[f])%n])s[c-f]++;s[c]=0;h=k;}d[m]=c;}}}free(d);free(j);free(r);s=v[n];f=strlen(s);s[f]=48;s[f+b]=0;mpz_init_set_str(B,s,10);mpz_init_set_si(I,i);mpz_init(Q);mpz_divexact(Q,B,I);d=mpz_get_str(0,10,Q);printf("%s\n",d);free(d);s[f+b]=48;s[f]=0;}return 0;}
```

#### Ungolfed loop version

```c
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **cache;

int main() {
    int i,n,shift,_kb,km,key,m,*ks,*ksi,*nksi,*res,*ii;
    char *d,*s;
    mpz_t B,I,Q;

    cache = calloc(10001,sizeof(char*));
    if (!cache) { printf("Failed to malloc cache\n"); return 1; }
    cache[1]=s = malloc(99);
    memset(s,48,99);
    *s=49;
    s[1]=0;
    for (i=0;++i<10001;) {
        n=i;
        for(shift=0;n%10<1;++shift)n/=10;
        for(;n%2<1;++shift)n/=2;
        for(;n%5<1;++shift)n/=5;

        d = calloc(n,1);
        if (!d) { printf("Failed to malloc d\n"); return 1; }

        ks = calloc(n,sizeof(int));
        if (!ks) { printf("Failed to malloc ks\n"); return 1; }

        res = calloc(99,sizeof(int));
        if (!res) { printf("Failed to malloc res\n"); return 1; }

        _kb = 2;
        d[1] = 1;
        *ks = res[1] = km = 1;
        nksi = ks + 1;

        for(;!cache[n];++_kb) {
            res[_kb] = km = km*10%n;
            ksi = nksi;
            for (ii = ks; ii < ksi; ii++) {
                key = *ii;
                m = (km + key) % n;
                if (d[m] < 1) {
                    *nksi++ = m;
                    if (m < 1) {
                        cache[n] = s = malloc(99);
                        if (!s) { printf("Failed to malloc s\n"); return 1; }
                        memset(s,48,99);
                        for(key=_kb;key;key = d[m = (m + n - res[key]) % n])s[_kb-key]++;
                        s[_kb]=0;
                        ii = ksi; // break
                    }
                    d[m] = _kb;
                }
            }
        }

        free(d);
        free(ks);
        free(res);

        // Add shift * '0'
        s=cache[n];
        key=strlen(s);
        s[key]=48;
        s[key+shift]=0;

        // convert to big integer, divide, print
        mpz_init_set_str(B,s,10);
        mpz_init_set_si(I,i);
        mpz_init(Q);
        mpz_divexact(Q,B,I);
        d = mpz_get_str(0,10,Q);
        if (!s) { printf("Failed to malloc quotient\n"); return 1; }
        printf("%s\n", d);
        free(d);

        // Remove shift * '0'
        s[key+shift]=48;
        s[key]=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C + GMP, 669

This is really fast for smallish numbers; it starts to choke when the result has more than 64 digits.

```c
#include<gmp.h>
#define B(x)(int)((x*(long)k)%n);
int*M,*H,P[99],n,x,p,q=2,e=1,k=10,y,f,z;char*E,C[99];int b(int k,int t){int
j=E[k],a=1<<(j-2);if(j<2){C[t]=49;return 1;}x=(int)((k+n-P[j]*(long)H[k]%n)%n);if(x)b(x,t);return a+b(H[k],t-a);}int
main(){scanf("%d",&n);E=calloc(n+1,1);M=calloc(n+1,4);H=malloc(n*4);M[1]=E[1%n]=P[1]=1;while(!E[0]){P[++e]=k;p=q;for(x=0;++x<p;){y=B(M[x])if(E[n-y]){E[0]=e;H[0]=M[x];break;}}if(!E[x=0])while(++x<p){y=B(M[x])for(z=0;z<p;++z){f=y+M[z];if(f>=n)f-=n;if(!E[f]){E[f]=e;H[f]=M[x];M[q++]=f;}}}k=B(k)}memset(C,48,98);C[99]=0;x=b(0,97);mpz_t
m,r;mpz_init(r);mpz_init_set_str(m,C+98-x,10);mpz_fdiv_q_ui(r,m,n);puts(mpz_get_str(C,10,r));}
```

Version that loops to 10000 (671 bytes):

```c
#include<gmp.h>
#define B(x)(int)((x*(long)k)%n);
#define N 10001
int M[N],H[N],P[99],n=0,x,p,q,e,k,y,f,z;char E[N],C[99];int b(int k,int t){int
j=E[k],a=1<<(j-2);if(j<2){C[t]=49;return 1;}x=(int)((k+n-P[j]*(long)H[k]%n)%n);if(x)b(x,t);return a+b(H[k],t-a);}int
main(){while(++n<N){memset(E,M[0]=0,n);M[1]=E[1%n]=P[1]=e=1;q=2;k=10;while(!E[0]){P[++e]=k;p=q;for(x=0;++x<p;){y=B(M[x])if(E[n-y]){E[0]=e;H[0]=M[x];break;}}if(!E[x=0])while(++x<p){y=B(M[x])for(z=0;z<p;++z){f=y+M[z];if(f>=n)f-=n;if(!E[f]){E[f]=e;H[f]=M[x];M[q++]=f;}}}k=B(k)}memset(C,48,98);C[99]=0;x=b(0,97);mpz_t
m,r;mpz_init(r);mpz_init_set_str(m,C+98-x,10);mpz_fdiv_q_ui(r,m,n);puts(mpz_get_str(C,10,r));}}
```

Here are some commands for testing my code as well as my competitors', and the results on my laptop:

```
ls -l *.c*       
-rw-r--r-- 1 aditsu aditsu  669 Oct 27 15:01 mult-aditsu-single.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 aditsu aditsu  671 Oct 27 15:01 mult-aditsu.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 aditsu aditsu 3546 Oct 27 15:01 mult-anatoly.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 aditsu aditsu 6175 Oct 27 15:01 mult-anders.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 aditsu aditsu  621 Oct 27 15:01 mult-peter-single.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 aditsu aditsu  751 Oct 27 15:01 mult-peter.c

gcc -w -march=native -O3 mult-aditsu-single.c -lgmp -o mult-aditsu-single
gcc -w -march=native -O3 mult-aditsu.c -lgmp -o mult-aditsu
gcc -w -march=native -O3 mult-peter-single.c -lgmp -o mult-peter-single
gcc -w -march=native -O3 mult-peter.c -lgmp -o mult-peter
gcc -w -march=native -O3 --std=c99 mult-anatoly.c -o mult-anatoly
g++ --std=c++11 -march=native -O3 mult-anders.cpp -o mult-anders

for i in {1..5}; do time ./mult-anders mult-anders.txt; done
./mult-anders mult-anders.txt  0.34s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.344 total
./mult-anders mult-anders.txt  0.36s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.358 total
./mult-anders mult-anders.txt  0.34s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.346 total
./mult-anders mult-anders.txt  0.35s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.347 total
./mult-anders mult-anders.txt  0.34s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.344 total

for i in {1..5}; do ./mult-anatoly mult-anatoly.txt; done
Time: 0.254416
Time: 0.253555
Time: 0.245734
Time: 0.243129
Time: 0.243345

for i in {1..5}; do time ./mult-peter > mult-peter.txt; done
./mult-peter > mult-peter.txt  0.14s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.137 total
./mult-peter > mult-peter.txt  0.15s user 0.00s system 97% cpu 0.153 total
./mult-peter > mult-peter.txt  0.15s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.149 total
./mult-peter > mult-peter.txt  0.15s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.150 total
./mult-peter > mult-peter.txt  0.14s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.138 total

for i in {1..5}; do time ./mult-aditsu > mult-aditsu.txt; done
./mult-aditsu > mult-aditsu.txt  0.06s user 0.00s system 95% cpu 0.058 total
./mult-aditsu > mult-aditsu.txt  0.05s user 0.00s system 97% cpu 0.055 total
./mult-aditsu > mult-aditsu.txt  0.06s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.056 total
./mult-aditsu > mult-aditsu.txt  0.05s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.054 total
./mult-aditsu > mult-aditsu.txt  0.05s user 0.00s system 98% cpu 0.055 total

md5sum *.txt
6eef8511d3bc5769b5d9218be2e00028  mult-aditsu.txt
6eef8511d3bc5769b5d9218be2e00028  mult-anatoly.txt
6eef8511d3bc5769b5d9218be2e00028  mult-anders.txt
6eef8511d3bc5769b5d9218be2e00028  mult-peter.txt
```

Comment: An answer well-deserving of a bounty. I take particular interest in this problem (and your initial solution), because it is a special case of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is known to be NP-complete (given a list of the residues of _10ⁱ_ mod _n_, find the earliest subset which sums to _n_).

Comment: @primo Thank you :) My approach here is different - I double the number of digits at each step rather than just incrementing it, and I also check first (very quickly) if any of the new numbers would be a solution, before actually calculating them. And I'm sure there's still room for golfing.

Comment: Interesting. When I tried doubling the number of digits at each step it ended up being slower. Maybe the pre-check for solutions makes a big difference.

Comment: @PeterTaylor that's possible.. it seems that you're also calling calloc in a loop, which might slow it down. Anyway, I'd like to add an ungolfed version of my code when I find some time, and I also have an idea how to make it faster for bigger/nastier numbers.

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, <strike>164</strike> <strike>156</strike> <strike>155</strike> <strike>154</strike> 159 bytes

(-1 byte. Thanks Jonathan!)

(-1 more because why do I have trailing spaces on lines? SMH)

(+5 realized my golfing broke things)

```
create function b(@ int)
returns int
as begin
declare @b varchar(max)='',@i int=@
while @>0SELECT @b=cast(@%2 as varchar)+@b,@/=2
return cast(@b as int)/@i
end
```

I don't know why I keep coming back to these questions where I'm supposed to convert to Binary... T-SQL doesn't know how to do that right.

In any case, here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9064e/1/0).

Un-golfed:

```
create function binarySquare(@id int)
returns int 
as BEGIN
```

Most of this stuff is required to write a function in T-SQL, as far as I'm aware.

```
    declare @bin nvarchar(max) = ''
```

Create a blank string that we're going to store as our binary number.

```
    declare @id2 int = @id
```

Save the input value for use at the end. It seems like there should be a way to use the original input even if we change the value, but I can't find one.

```
    while @id>0
      BEGIN
        SET @bin = cast(@id%2 as varchar(1)) + @bin
```

So we take our original input, MOD it with 2 to find the remainder, and that's going to be our next smallest digit. For example, 5%2 = 1

```
        SET @id = @id/2
```

Then we take our number, and divide it in half. Because it's an `int` type, it rounds it down to the nearest whole number, so 5/2 = 2. 
          END
We then loop through this until the value is 0. So we end up with 
    5%2 = 1    5/2 = 2
    2%2 = 0    2/2 = 1
    1%2 = 1    1/2 = 0 
which gives us our binary string value of 101.

```
    declare @binNum int = (SELECT cast(@bin as int))
```

We take our binary string and convert it back to an `int` again.

```
    return @binNum/@id2
```

We return our binary string `int` divided by our original value, per the origin of the question.

```
END
```

Comment: Is the space in `@>0 SELECT` not omittable?

Comment: Nice catch! I can never remember what spaces are omit-able...

Comment: Most of the time you can omit spaces in between literals and variables / keywords, as they cannot begin with a digit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 38 bytes (brute force approach)

```
~n=(i=0;while"$((i+=1)n)"⊈"01"end;i)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjfV6vJsNTJtDazLMzJzUpVUNDQytW0NNfM0lR51dSgZGCql5qVYZ2pCVQeVFmfmpSsEFGXmlaRxRStoVCrYKtRVWCs4FICFNJRUjTIVDk9XUNU1NMgEyqlmxuQp6ShU6ChUAkmtSk1NhbT8IoUKhcw8BUMrI1OFWIjJMPcAAA)

- -7 bytes (!!) thanks to MarcMush: rewrite with `⊈` instead of `maximum`
- -1 byte thanks to MarcMush: increment `i` inside the loop evaluation

Comment: 38 bytes with `⊈`: [`~n=(i=0;while"$((i+=1)n)"⊈"01"end;i)`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjfV6vJsNTJtDazLMzJzUpVUNDQytW0NNfM0lR51dSgZGCql5qVYZ2pCVQeVFmfmpSsEFGXmlaRxRStoVCrYKtRVWCs4FICFNJRUjTIVDk9XUNU1NMgEyqlmxuQp6ShU6ChUAkmtSk1NhbT8IoUKhcw8BUMrI1OFWIjJMPcAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 46 bytes

I should really eliminate the while loop with an alternative loop.

```
n,k=gets,0;$_="#{n.to_i*k+=1}"while/[^01]/;p k
```

Edit: Thanks @manatwork for shaving off 1 byte!

Edit2: Thanks @histocraft for the insane 9 bytes!

Edit: Thanks @manatwork again for shaving off 7 bytes!

Comment: `z!=z[/[01]+/]` is shorter. `z[/[^01]/]` is even more shorter.

Comment: @manatwork Thanks! 1 byte less!

Comment: Single-line while loops tend to be the shortest: `z="#{n.to_i*k+=1}"while z[/[^01]/]`

Comment: @histocrat That's 9 bytes! And I didn't even know that ruby is capable of this. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting that you not changed the test to negated character set neither after was suggested 2nd time. Any reason?

Comment: @manatwork I've thought about that and tried it but the loop never ended for me (which is strange)

Comment: oh, must be because of the trailing newline returned by `gets` the way you're invoking it.

Comment: With some Perlish flavor: `n=gets;k=0;$_="#{n.to_i*k+=1}"while/[^01]/;p k`.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 114 Bytes

```
val i=scala.io.StdIn.readInt;Stream.from(1).foreach{x=>if((i*x+"").map{_.asDigit}.max<2){print(x);System.exit(0)}}
```

Readable version

```
val i=scala.io.StdIn.readInt
Stream.from(1).foreach{x => 
    if((i*x+"").map{_.asDigit}.max<2) {
        print(x)
        System.exit(0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## gawk4 brute force, 28+2 = 30 bytes

```awk
{while(++n*$0~/[2-9]/);}$0=n
```

Needs to be called with the `-M` option for using big numbers. Of course this is ridiculously slow, using big numbers slows it down even more, but theoretically the input is not limited, and RAM usage is negligible.

#### Usage example ( if you got time to waste `;)`)

```sh
echo 27 | awk -M '{while(++n*$0~/[2-9]/);}$0=n'
```

## gawk4 optimized, 69+2 = 71 bytes

```awk
{for(;!a[0];NR*=10)for(i in a)a[j=(s=a[i]+NR)%$0]?0:a[j]=s}$0=a[0]/$0
```

Well, this ended up being a clone of aditsu's answer. After looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388165/how-to-find-the-smallest-number-with-just-0-and-1-which-is-divided-by-a-give) I was still figuring out how to code the subset-sum part, when I couldn't resist looking at the other answers here.

In awk array elements have the (strange ?) behaviour that if you compare a non-existing element to something it is somehow initialized as empty before being compared (I'll admit that I'm not quite sure about what is happening there). So after checking `!a[0]` the `for(i in a)` loop starts even without initializing `a[$0]` to `0` as aditsu did.

Of course the `-M` option has to be used for this too.

Though it is rather fast it is still remarkably slower than Python. For `79992` this takes around 14 seconds on my 2GHz Core2Duo. And I wouldn't say it works for inputs up to 2^31, because in the worst case it has to build an array of big numbers (gawk4 uses GMP for this), which has the size of the input number. As a 'bonus' large arrays are very very slow in awk...

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 25

This defines a proper program "P" (not just an unnamed function):

```
P←2∘{0::⍵∇⍨1+⍺⋄⍺⊣~⍎¨⍕⍺×⍵}
```

`2∘` begin with 2 as left argument
`0::` if there is any error...
`⍵∇⍨1+⍺` call itself with an incremented left argument
`⍺×⍵` multiply left and right arguments
`⍕` make into string
`⍎¨` make each character into a number
`~` attempt logical NOT (if it fails, go to error-handling above, else...)
`⍺⊣` return the current left argument.

```
      P 2
50
      P 21
481
      P¨⍳8    ⍝ 1 through 8
10 5 37 25 2 185 143 125
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
×QḌ=⁵ð1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//w5dR4biMPeKBtcOwMSP/w4figqz//zIsIDIx)

Tied Pyth!

### How it works

```
×QḌ=⁵ð1# - Main link. Takes n on the left
     ð   - Combine the previous links into a dyad f(i, n):
×        -   i×n
 Q       -   Unique digits
  Ḍ      -   Convert into an integer
   =⁵    -   Does this equal 10?
           f(i, n) returns true for a given i if i×n only consists of 1 and 0
      1# - Starting from n, find the first integer i = n, n+1, ... such that f(i, n) is true
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
∞›*'S₀S↔=;h$/
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%88%9E%E2%80%BA*%27S%E2%82%80S%E2%86%94%3D%3Bh%24%2F&inputs=3&header=&footer=)

```
∞›*           # All multpiles of n
   '     ;    # Filtered by
    S₀S↔      # When you remove all the digits except 0 and 1
        =     # Does it equal itself?
          h   # Get the first item for which this happens
           $/ # Divide by n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ƙ×Gḅ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU5OCVDMyU5N0clRTElQjglODUmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0yMSZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
Ƙ×Gḅ  # Implicit input
Ƙ     # First integer where:
 ×    #  Multiply by the input
  G   #  Maximum digit
   ḅ  #  Equals one?
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 82 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 10.25 bytes

```
¨*'₀τGċ¬;h?/
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiwqgqJ+KCgM+ER8SLwqw7aD8vIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 44 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 5.5 bytes

```
?*↑ṅ)ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiPyrihpHhuYUp4bmFIiwiIiwiMiJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 36 bytes

```powershell
for(;++$i*"$args"-replace"[01]"){}$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZlv9Py2/SMNaW1slU0tJJbEovVhJtyi1ICcxOVUp2sAwVkmzulYl838tF5eaSpqCEYQ0/A8A)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 156+31=187 bytes

The code requires the following usings:

```
using System;using System.Linq;
```

Here the code:

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){var b=ulong.Parse(Console.ReadLine());var d=1U;for(;(b*d).ToString().Any(x=>x!='0'&&x!='1');d++);Console.WriteLine(d);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        var b = ulong.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var d = 1U;
        for (; (b*d).ToString().Any(x => x != '0' && x != '1'); d++);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### SAS, 81 bytes

This is give or take the same approach as some of the 'fast' python approaches above: iterate through the possible binary numbers, pretend they're decimal, test them.

```
data a;b=72;do until(a=int(a));y+1;a=input(put(y,binary32.),32.)/b;end;put a;run;
```

Unfortunately I can't skip the input/put, because the default width for implicit conversions is only 12 (meaning it quickly becomes "1e8" and similar which fails).

Ungolfed:

```
data a;
  b=72;
  do until(a=int(a));
    y+1;
    a=input(put(y,binary32.),32.)/b;
  end;
  put a;
run;
```

This isn't entirely safe; for larger numbers (which have no solution in a double precision floating point environment) this could turn into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby 46 bytes

No better in # of bytes than the previous Ruby solution by the Peter Lenkefi, but slightly different approach:

```
gets;p 1.step.find{|i|"#{$_.to_i*i}"!~/[^01]/}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Burlesque, 24 bytes

Found a shorter version:

```
1R@?*b0{{"10"j~[}al}fi?i
```

Older Versions:

```
1R@?*b0{"\`[01]*\\'"~=}fi?i
```

It's terribly slow though if the number can't be found fast.

```
1R@?*b0{"23456789"INnu}fi?i
```

This version might be faster because it doesn't use regexes. Still terribly slow though.

There's no limit except the time it takes to find the answer which can be quite long.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
È*U skA}f1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yCpVIHNrQX1mMQ&input=MjE) - Be careful with multiples of `9` ;)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
ḟö=1▲d*⁰N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9odXNr///huJ/Dtj0x4payZCrigbBO////MjE)

```
ḟö=1▲d*⁰N
ḟö              # first truthy element of:
      *⁰N       # multiply all natural numbers by input
    ▲d          # max of decimal digits
  =1            # equals 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1..).find{(_1*n).digits.max<2}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3VXTt8qo1DPX0NPXSMvNSqjXiDbXyNPVSMtMzS4r1chMrbIxqayFq1xUouEUbxXKBKcNYiOCCBRAaAA)