# (RGS 1/5) Binary multiples

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, number-theory, integer

A *binary multiple* of a positive integer `k` is a positive integer `n` such that `n` is written only with `0`s and `1`s in base 10 and `n` is a multiple of `k`. For example, `111111` is a *binary multiple* of 3.

It is easy to show that a positive integer has infinitely many *binary multiples*. See [here](https://mathspp.com/blog/binary-multiples) for a construction proof of one *binary multiple* for each `k`. Multiplying by powers of `10` you get infinitely many more.

## Your task

Given a positive integer `k`, return the smallest binary multiple of `k`.

## Input

A positive integer `k`.

## Output

A positive integer `n`, the smallest binary multiple of `k`.

## Test cases

```
2 -> 10
3 -> 111
4 -> 100
5 -> 10
6 -> 1110
7 -> 1001
8 -> 1000
9 -> 111111111
10 -> 10
11 -> 11
12 -> 11100
13 -> 1001
14 -> 10010
15 -> 1110
16 -> 10000
17 -> 11101
18 -> 1111111110
19 -> 11001
20 -> 100
100 -> 100
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest submission in bytes, wins! If you liked this challenge, consider upvoting it... And happy golfing!

---

This is the first challenge of the [RGS Golfing Showdown](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18545/75323). If you want to participate in the competition, you have 96 hours to submit your eligible answers. Remember there is 450 reputation in prizes! (See **6** of [the rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18545/75323))

Otherwise, this is still a regular [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so enjoy!

Comment: Related: [One-zero dividend](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74391/20260). I think this isn't a duplicate though because in that challenge all the 1's had to come before all the 0's and you didn't have to output the smallest instance.

Comment: @xnor thanks! Looking forward for your submission

Comment: This is [OEIS A004290](http://oeis.org/A004290).

Comment: So which answer surprised you the most?

Comment: @a'_' ahaha incredible. Are you going to post an answer in Roj?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/60942/25315)

Answer (score 13):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
∞b.ΔIÖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8JL1zUzwPT/v/39ACAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WeWilvZLCo7ZJCkr2/x91zEvSOzfl0LrD0/7X6vyPNtQx0jHWMdEx1THTMdex0LHUMTTQMTTUMTTSMTTWMTTRMTTVMTTTMTTXMbTQMbTUMQLKGhjEAgA) *(courtesy of @KevinCruijssen)*

---

### Explanation

```
∞b           - Infinite binary list
  .Δ         - Find the first value such that..
    IÖ       - It's divisible by the input
```

Comment: Short answer, good job! Do you think you can add the TIO link with all the test cases?

Comment: @RGS [Here ya go.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WeWilvZLCo7ZJCkr2/x91zEvSOzfl0LrD0/7X6vyPNtQx0jHWMdEx1THTMdex0LHUMTTQMTTUMTTSMTTWMTTRMTTVMTTTMTTXMbTQMbTUMQLKGhjEAgA) ;)

Comment: Thanks @KevinCruijssen was going to have to go work out how to do that ;)

Comment: @ExpiredData Ah, shall I delete it so it'll be a learning curve for you? ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen nah I would have just gone and stolen it from another one of your answers

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
f=lambda k,n=0:n*(max(`n`)<'2')or f(k,n+k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCoMwEADvfcXezDZ7SHJqpL6kCEY0dkldJXior48BbzMMzH4e301cKbH7hXWcAiSSzrTyVGv4q0EGfDeuwS1DVDXphCVWYWCBHGSZlSOP@kZryL5Qf6wnV9GYvn0A7JnlAKZ6YCwX)

---

Full program, same length:

```python
a=b=input()
while'1'<max(`b`):b+=a
print b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2yTYzr6C0REOTqzwjMydV3VDdJjexQiMhKUHTKknbNpGroCgzr0Qh6f9/YwA)

Comment: Nice Python submission! If the full program is the same length and doesn't exceed the Recursion Depth, why don't you use it as the "main" submission? :)

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
`@YBUG\}HM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8Eh0inUPabWw/f/f0MLAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##LY1BC4JAFITv/YohEG9hHj1ZQcZS3YqigtZ1Q0F9y/MZeei3m5Vznfm@qbSU/SWMwgDzILgBHhbMugM9ILYRFLVrpZlM45N64R8PWyIHeloe6xlW5DqYltnWIwMhmLJwKWnOoPp7fF4e1PW92X0NexKLBEUDtq7UxmZIu2Gljn4EP83z38@auNICamUQ9h8).

#### Explanation

```
`      % Do...while
  @    %   Push iteration index (1-based)
  YB   %   Convert to binary string (1 gvies '1', 2 gives '10,  etc).
  U    %   Convert string to number ('10' gives 10). This is the current
       %   solution candidate
  G    %   Push input
  \    %   Modulo. Gives 0 if the current candidate is a multiple of the
       %   input, which will cause the loop to exit
}      % Finally: execute on loop exit
  H    %   Push 2
  M    %   Push input to the second-last normal function (`U`); that is,
       %   the candidate that caused the loop to exit, in string form
       % End (implicit). If top of the stack is 0: the loop exits.
       % Otherwise: a new iteration is run
       % Display (implicit)
```

Comment: "Ah, why is there a bug in my program? Hm..."

Comment: I [removed the bug](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8EhMqbWw/f/f0MLAA) but I don't think I fixed it :( +1!

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

Looks for the smallest \$n\$ such that the decimal representation of \$p=n\times k\$ is made exclusively of \$0\$'s and \$1\$'s.

```javascript
f=(k,p=k)=>/[2-9]/.test(p)?f(k,p+k):p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcm7DoIwFAbg3afoZk/8LRzAG6Y4@QSOhqEB6gXTNtD4@hWnb/je5mvmbnqFuHW@H1KyWo4IeiTdZPdie2ozFYc5ykAX@5/NSHVI53uBEhV22OOAIzgHM7gAl@AKvAPvwQfwCcVSed6ulPXT1XRP6YRuROfd7D@D@viHdCr6W5xe7iFJBdPfopmiLElsxLoW6wUrHRGlHw) (some test cases removed because of recursion overflow)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 41 bytes

Looks for the smallest \$n\$ such that \$k\$ divides the binary representation of \$n\$ parsed in base \$10\$.

```javascript
k=>(g=n=>(s=n.toString(2))%k?g(n+1):s)(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY27DoJAFAV7v2Ibw95wJFyQp1ms/AJKY7HhJUJ2CWz8faSzOVNMMuejv3pr1nFxF2Pbbu/VPqlKDsocuykTOFu7dTSDjIjO032QxmcqN5JM@@0ZIcYVCVJkyFGAQzCDI3AMvoITcArOwDm4QHTYMHydgt6uD928pRGqEo01m527YLZH/P9HwaLb2unVyZiEL7xSeAd6aYho/wE) (all test cases)

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>50</s> 38 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Giuseppe.

```r
grep("^[01]+$",(k=scan())*1:10^k)[1]*k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P70otUBDKS7awDBWW0VJRyPbtjg5MU9DU1PL0MrQIC5bM9owViv7v9l/AA)

It follows from [this blog post](https://mathspp.com/blog/binary-multiples) (linked in the question) that the smallest binary multiple of \$k\$ is smaller than \$2\cdot10^{k-1}\$; this answer uses the larger bound \$k\cdot10^k\$ instead.

Creates a vector of all multiples of \$k\$ between \$k\$ and \$k\cdot10^k\$. The regexp gives the indices of those made only of 0s and 1s; select the first index and multiply by \$k\$ to get the answer.

Will time out on TIO for input greater than 8, but with infinite memory it would work for any input.

Comment: Use `grepl`! [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9u2ODkxT0PTujwjMydVI70otSBHQynaSNcyVknHzUbXTTtbU9PA2u2/2X8A). I came here to comment a `grepl` approach based on my SNOBOL answer and found your regex to be better :-) I had `!grepl("^[10]+$",F)` for the record.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks! I knew about `grepl` but somehow convinced myself that it led to a longer answer... Your version is cleaner!

Comment: @Giuseppe Changed again, this time using your original regexp in another `grep` solution.

Comment: Quite clever! Glad I could be of assistance with that! :-)

Answer (score 8):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 38 bytes

```php
while(($n=decbin(++$x))%$argn);echo$n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBbT8IwFH7fr/iyzGwLI1CQi85BSJRIQpQE38SYOStbgt1cOyQx/vbZrR1gX3rO@S7nksVZeTPN4swwLEG54AjwbAA9BBOQrifDfh0SUsWXqlzXByfKUFPqZKQ5tWCskxq50jT1qgrpnkwIUXAd9xpHBfXPPUkzhdYNzruTYdNRpaMGVNLxvxEURY@l3Xvdsx3ld8xefMPodFBdCVHIKUfBE7aFFeZbBod@Fck@3FEmIFKsn24XD5ogr4v23DU@0pyGUexAXzrkWis7WDnlxU7AxY9sS6M4VZgHE@0JTL/8jpMddRyLBe80ekuY02pZB9e9qGmuX0ks5pdabGIjNsL0YEn74Gg/hb2ardc2rmHPZ4ul7WF1v3q9e1z6sq3cTvKoAGX7JE/Zp1xGlgsma3LqA1wfgPFb/gE)

Counts up `n` in binary and divides it's decimal representation by `k` until there is no remainder; indicating the first, smallest multiple.

Comment: Thanks for your PHP submission and thorough test case coverage! +1

Answer (score 7):

## T-SQL, 57 bytes

This script is really slow when using 18 as input

```sql
DECLARE @z INT = 18

DECLARE @ int=1WHILE
@z*@ like'%[^10]%'SET @+=1PRINT @z*@
```

## T-SQL, 124 bytes

T-SQL doesn't have binary conversion

This will execute fast:

```sql
DECLARE @ int=1,@x char(64)=0,@a int=2WHILE 
@x%@z>0or @x=0SELECT
@x=left(concat(@%2,@x),@),@a-=1/~@,@=@/2-1/~@*-~@a
PRINT @x
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1203060/rgs-1-5-binary-multiples)**

Comment: I just can't seem to accept that SQL solves these challenges +1... What is the T- in T-SQL?

Comment: @RGS sql really is horrible for golfing, but it is the only language I know well enough to golf at this level, sql is also it is quite readable(maybe not in this case, but that is not the sql part). T stands for Transact.

Comment: maybe it wasn't clear, but I am impressed by your submissions! I wasn't trying to put you down or anything! keep up the really interesting work :D

Comment: @RGS not to worry, I took it as a compliment. It's cool that you post so many interesting questions.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I try to, at least :) See you next challenge!

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
≔1ηＷ﹪ＩηＩθ≔⍘⊕⍘η²¦²ηη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU9DyVBJRyFD05qrPCMzJ1VBwzc/pTQnX8M5sbhEI0NTRwHMKNTU1FSAanBKLE4NLinKzEvX8MxLLkrNTc0rSU1BFs7QUTDS1AQREJMDgKIgw6z//ze0/K9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔1η
```

Start at `1`.

```
Ｗ﹪ＩηＩθ
```

Repeat until a multiple of `n` is found, treating the values as base 10.

```
≔⍘⊕⍘η²¦²η
```

Convert from base 2, increment, then convert back to base 2.

```
η
```

Output the result.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>44 38</s> 36 bytes

Saved two bytes by using `filter` as suggested by @ovs.

```hs
f k=filter(all(<'2').show)[0,k..]!!1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h2zYtM6cktUgjMSdHw0bdSF1Trzgjv1wz2kAnW08vVlHR8H9uYmaebUFRZl6JgopCmoKh5X8A)

This checks all multiples of `k` and is slow for input 9 and 18.

I much prefer this version which defines the list of all "binary" numbers and searches for the first multiple of `k` among them. It quickly handles all test cases, but needs  52 bytes:

```hs
b=1:[10*x+d|x<-b,d<-[0,1]]
f k=[m|m<-b,mod m k<1]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYyxCsIwGIT3PsVVHNQ05Y@jJD6BTo4hSEqUSpqm2Iod@u4xOnjDx/EdXGtHf@u6lBolDlrQbmZumSVvKie5pkoYU9zhlQ5L@NoQHQK8FKYsKcW8DK/pMj1PPdYY2/iGB2NYgR8zcvu5Tb7YFsE@eii4iGCH8xURWtT1nkyBfyIEUfoA)

Comment: [2 bytes shorter](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h2zYtM6cktUgjMSdHIyE1JzU3QcnAUElTrzgjv1wz2kAnW08vVlHR8H9uYmaebUFRZl6JgopCmoKh5X8A) with `filter`.

Comment: @ovs Thanks, that still applies to my newer version. Somehow I always feel that list comprehension must be shorter...

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
È*nvU}a¤
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yCpudlV9YaQ&input=MTg)

Comment: Really cool solution, and it is crazy fast +1! Is it fast because of the algorithm used or because of the Japt machinery?

Comment: I think this fails for 11.

Comment: It's probably because 11 is crossed out in the program length part.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/),, <sup><s>75</s>\$\cdots\$ <s>50</s></sup> 52 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Mukundan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91267/mukundan)!!!
Added 2 bytes to fix error kindly pointed out by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe).

```python
f=lambda k,n=1:(i:=int(f"{n:b}"))%k and f(k,n+1)or i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDbaoQwEIbvfYrBpZCwKRjdgxXSyz5B70ovsuvIhl2jxAgW8dltDvaQq2/m@ycT0n/ZW6eLsjfr2oiHbC@1hDvTgldEVUJpS5p01tVlSSl9uoPUNTTEBfacdgbUasT8bkasUjmkDN7kY3CsOwuuXpLGZSxDUBpIQnLGM8oSUjDOuYeDa4TOcTMnbwKdGTgXUmXA0H1x@HN8zTPvAnGvAuUhFAd48XcPP0SO4hhTgU9xQyzOUfiRHeHlv43O73C6ItYDtHJS7diCwetoBtVpqLG3Nzcf3ritzMP74r3ZL9Mqgd5sf2sXeH6FuSGWLjCbDw9C4OcCOPV4tVindP0G)

Comment: you can save 2 bytes by doing `f'{n:b}'` instead of `bin(n)[2:]` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDLbsMgEEX3/oqRpSigUsnYeThIdNkv6K7tgtSgWEmxRajUCvHtLgzpg9WZOZcZxPzlT5Pt@tktRr4sF/V@HBScmZVckFHI0Xpi1sGKY1xTujqDsgMYkgJ3nE4OxsXJ8OQ@tKjVtWbwqC7XxHbykOpYmZTxTMNogVSkZbyhrCId45xn2KQGdrY3s8sGac8gOUz1iNg9JPw5ueZNdkg8K6QWQ@UC7/7m8E3hIrYlhbwrG0qxL6Jc6f8tLBqfcJvY4vrSb36Zigpmh19XBx/h/gGCIZ5GCO45g5T6NYL@nPWb10NNl28 "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Mukundan Clever use of f-strings - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 6):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, 52 bytes

```bash
for((n=1;n%$1;));do n=`dc<<<2dio1d$n+p`;done
echo $n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEMjz9bQOk9VxdBaU9M6JV8hzzYhJdnGxsYoJTPfMEUlT7sgASicl8qVmpyRr6CS9///f0NzAA)

This counts in binary, views the resulting numbers in base 10, and stops when a multiple of the input is reached.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
‘¡DṀḊƊ¿
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9qZWxsef//4oCYwqFE4bmA4biKxorCv////zY)**

#### How?

Note that in Jelly empty lists are falsey, while other lists are truthy. Also dequeue, `Ḋ`, is a monadic atom which removes the first item from a list, but when presented with only an integer Jelly will first convert that integer to a list by forming the range `[1..n]` thus `Ḋ` yields `[2..n]`.

```
‘¡DṀḊƊ¿ - Link: integer, k
      ¿ - while...
     Ɗ  - ...condition: last three links as a monad:
  D     -     decimal digits   e.g. 1410 -> [1,4,1,0]  or 1010 -> [1,0,1,0]
   Ṁ    -     maximum                       4                     1
    Ḋ   -     dequeue (implicit range of)   [2,3,4]               []
        -                                   (truthy)              (falsey)
 ¡      - ...do: repeat (k times):
‘       -     increment
```

For some reason, when the body of a while loop, `¿`, is a dyad each iteration sets the left argument to the result **and** then sets the right argument to the value of the left argument, so the 6 byte `+DṀḊƊ¿` does not work. (For example given `3` that would: test `3`; perform `3+3`; test `6`; perform `6+3`; test `9`; perform `9+6`; test `15`; perform `15+9`; etc...)

---

**[Previous 8](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9qZWxsef//ROG4gsaRyKfhu43DsDEj////Ng):**

```
DḂƑȧọð1#
```

(`DḂƑ` could be `DỊẠ` too.)

**[An alternative](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l4c4GbdWHu7sObzBU/v//vxkA) 8**:

```
DṀ+%Ịð1#
```

Answer (score 5):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), <del>7</del> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

<sup>-1 because I realized that W has operator overloading over `t`.</sup>

```
•B⌡≡kü
```

Uncompressed:

```
*Tt!iX*
```

[repl.it](https://repl.it/@wgolf/w) is quite slow and you need to type in the program in code.w.

### Explanation

````
        % For every number in the range
    i   % from 1 to infinity:
     X  % Find the first number that satisfies
*       %     Multiply the current item by the input
 T      %     The constant for 10
  t     %     Remove all digits of 1 and 0 in the current item
        %     Both operands are converted to a string, just like in 05AB1E.
   !    %     Negate - checks whether it contains only 1 and 0.

      * % Multiply that result with the input (because it's the counter value).
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your W submission! I never understood why you include some code, and then right after it you say "uncompressed" and then include some other code. What does it mean?

Comment: The first code snippet is a compressed form of the W program, compressed in order to use up all 256 codepoints of CP437. However, there's also another non-compressed form that is human-writable (I compress my source code from on this form). The next code snippet is a human-readable non-compressed form of the W program (hence the "uncompressed"), which is part of the explanation.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand better now.

Comment: Where is the "get smallest" part?

Comment: The wiki says `X` is `SW` and `S` is swap while `W` is described as "keeps the specified item**s**...", is something in the wiki wrong or have I misinterpreted or missed something? Also could you link to an online evaluator (e.g. get it on TIO)? (By the way I did not know you replied, do use @)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Whoops, I forgot to add that `W`'s behavior is different with an infinity value. Nice catch. There isn't an online interpreter with a permalink for W yet, I'm waiting for Dennis to recover.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 68 bytes

```
.+
$*1:1,1;
{`^(1+):\1+,(.+);
$2
T`d`10`.1*;
,0
,10
1+,(.+)
$1$*1,$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRcvQylDH0JqrOiFOw1Bb0yrGUFtHQ09b05pLxYgrJCElwdAgQc9Qy5pLx4BLx9CACyrNpWII1KqjYvj/v6ElAA) Somewhat slow so no test suite. Explanation:

```
.+
$*1:1,1;
```

Initialise the work area with `n` in unary, `k` in unary, and `k` in decimal.

```
{`^(1+):\1+,(.+);
$2
```

If `n` divides `k` then delete everything except the result. This causes the remaining matches to fail and eventually the loop exits because it fails to achieve anything further.

```
T`d`10`.1*;
,0
,10
```

Treat `k` as a binary number and increment it.

```
1+,(.+)
$1$*1,$1
```

Regenerate the unary conversion of `k`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Core utilities, 40 bytes

```bash
seq $1 $1 $[10**$1]|grep ^[01]*$|head -1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UEHFEIyiDQ20tFQMY2vSi1ILFOKiDQxjtVRqMlITUxR0Df///28OAA)

Comment: Nice bash submission +1! Also harnessing the power of regexs, aren't you?

Comment: This is really nice.  Is it mathematically guaranteed that the solution will be less than or equal to `10^input`?

Comment: @Jonah Yes, in the question, RGS posted a link to a proof that there is always some value that works, and the proof actually yields that upper bound. Here’s the link: https://mathspp.com/blog/binary-multiples

Comment: @Jonah In fact, the upper bound proven is `10^input - 1` but it would take more bytes in the bash code to stop at that point.  Of course, there's no harm done by producing the one extra value.

Comment: @Jonah Sorry, the upper bound proven is the number consisting of n 1s, which is even less than I had said.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>42</s> <s>40</s> 36 bytes

```ruby
->k{z=k;z+=k until z.digits.max<2;z}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y67uso227pK2zZboTSvJDNHoUovJTM9s6RYLzexwsbIuqr2v4aRnp6RgaZeamJyRnVNZk1BaUmxgpJqsYKunYJqsZJqdKZOWnRmbGztfwA)

Very slow for 18, but ultimately gets the job done.

4 bytes golfed down by G B.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 10, <s>62</s> <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```java
n->{var r=n;for(;!(r+"").matches("[01]+");)r+=n;return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bU/LbsIwELzzFVOfbFlESY@46R@UC0fEwTUGTJMNWjuRKpRvT50Ublx29jE7mrnawa6vx5/JNTZGfNlA9xUQKHk@WeexnUeg6egMJxcgZfJuXOUSk03BYQtCjYnWn/fBMrgmc@pYmjfJWghVtDa5i49S7MvqoIUyinXmsE89E9iMk5nVbv13k9UeokMXjmizIblLHOi8P8Cqfzez@GIl1JVB@Kjfywxaq@UK7H5j8m3R9am45dfUkAxabCA0FU4GtQR4SRNVWT55uVWPqOP0Bw)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{             // Method with long as both parameter and return-type
  var r=n;       //  Result-long, starting at the input
  for(;!(r+"").matches("[01]+");)
                 //  Loop as long as `r` does NOT consists of only 0s and 1s
    r+=n;        //   Increase `r` by the input
  return r;}     //  After the loop is done, return `r` as result
```

This method above only works for binary outputs \$\leq1111111111111111111\$. For arbitrary large outputs - given enough time and resources - the following can be used instead (**<s>99</s> <s>70</s> 64 bytes**):

```java
n->{var r=n;for(;!(r+"").matches("[01]+");)r=r.add(n);return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY89b4MwEIZ3fsXVky0rFnSsS4ZuHZoOGaMMVzDEFEx0GKQq4rfTI83I0OVO9/Xc@zY44a4pv5eixWGAD/ThlgD4EB1VWDg4rCVAw3umw3gxb75@52ntCAq52Q7K8s2ccBgiRl/AAQLksITd/jYhAeXBVj1J@yRJC6FWQnFxgxSnNDtroayinAyWpWQWuThSALLzYlfmdfxqmflAT70voWPZ8hjJh/p0BlR/mtcXbAR8nlnwr/lzyklrdR8CHH@G6DrTj9Fc@TK2QXotXkDoYLadmQnb0X1W0it197gJEVma/ovCew/OnMzLLw)

Comment: Isn't the reason the first code fails numeric type limitations, and doesn't everybody pretend they do not exist?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate You're correct. I just figured I'd add a lambda function using `java.math.BigInteger` instead of `int`/`long` to prove it is possible to support an arbitrary large output if you'd want to.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 21 +2 (-ap) = 23 bytes

```perl
$_+=$F[0]while/[^01]/
```

Run with `-a` and `-p`, input to stdin. Just keeps repeatedly adding the input for as long as the result contains anything other than digits 0 and 1.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXttWxS3aILY8IzMnVT86zsAwVv//f7N/@QUlmfl5xf91EwsA)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 80 bytes

```c
r,m,n;b(h){for(r=0,m=1;h;h/=2)r+=h%2*m,m*=10;h=r;}f(k){for(n=1;b(++n)%k;);b(n);}
```

This can probably be improved some but I have yet to find a way.

Converts the integer into binary and checks if it's a multiple.

Brute-force.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/bbsIwDIbv8xQWU6WEmhF3RxTCi7BejJQuEWuK2rKLoT5759INbbNk@fTZ@u0Wb84NQ4MVRrOTXp3LupGN1VhZMt74pc1Uk1qfZPMKq7klbbxtTF/Kw8RG5nYyTaNKDkZxGpXph5sQ3fup2MO67YpQ3/qNECF2UL2GKD/qUChxFsA2NkM8nrp2m4O9tKbBaBnCHcI9wgPCI8ITwjPCCq9z0ghE7AwSk8QoMUsME9PEOK0QMv1757vojbjE8YlRhQML2nBYQxs@93UpJ11q@afc6lwxlabqn9hjw1dKOUsKWGwgKV7iDH9ecznC9YDLlTKTBNEPXw)

Comment: Very clever how `f()` only needs to call `b()` (which assigns return value to parameter) rather than assign return value to parameter!

Comment: @Noodle9 I wish I could omit the double-call but `div` puts the result of modulo in `eax` (which means `eax` will always be `0` after the loop).

Comment: Do you mean the modulo result is in `edx`?

Comment: @640KB Yes. I didn't look up the docs beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>24</sup> <sup>23</sup> 22 bytes

```
+^:(0<10#@-.~&":])^:_~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/teOsNAxsDA2UHXT16tSUrGI146zi6/5rcqUmZ@QrGBoo2CqkKRhBeYaGYK4xTBIia4Ki1hSuFsI3gyuGaDaH8yHyFnD1EAAWtEQx0tAApgbCNURYAVVghGaJIcKJMDNM0NxlaIpwCFTEDKEEagzMsQiDLVH9bmSAygfSXH5OegqofoLKWXD9BwA)

Add the number to itself `+` while `^:...^:_` the following is true:

`(0<10#@-.~&":])` - Something other than the digits 0 and 1 appear in the stringified number.

Comment: I like your submission. Can't even tell why

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```python
f=lambda k,n=0:n*({*str(n)}<={*"01"})or f(k,n+k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BCsIwEADvfcUaL0kbIdGLFvMS8RCbrQ2t25JEUErfHgPeZmBglm8aZjrl3JvJvh7OwijJqJZqvtYxBU5iu5q1ZkqzTcwBel6CZhS5L@LBE0w@Jh4sPZFredRCNDet1L2twPel2Bm4gCX3R31uYZ8GjAidjRgBPx2ig4DdO0Q/Ezhc0gAVwBI8Je4lOzBZtl6I/AM)

### Explanation

- `n` represents the current multiple of `k`.
- `{*str(n)}<={*"01"}` checks if `n` only contains digits `0` or `1`. This is done by creating a set of characters of `n`, then checks if that set is a subset of \$\{0,1\}\$.
- `n*({*str(n)}<={*"01"}) or f(k,n+k)` is arranged such that the recursive call `f(k,n+k)` is only evaluated when `n` is 0 or `n` is not a binary multiple of `k`. Here multiplication acts as a logical `and`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 49 bytes

```
(x=#;While[Or@@(#>1&)/@IntegerDigits@x,x=x+#];x)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X6PCVtk6PCMzJzXav8jBQUPZzlBNU9/BM68kNT21yCUzPbOk2KFCp8K2Qls51rpCU@1/QFFmXomCQ3q0cez//wA)

Comment: This fails on 11 (and, likely, 9) - the code should output *the smallest* binary multiple, and this one outputs the first one that has both zeroes and ones. [0-byte fix](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X6PCVtk6PCMzJzXav8jBQUPZzlBNU9/BM68kNT21yCUzPbOkOLoiVqfCtkJbOda6QlPtf0BRZl6JgkN6tKFh7P//AA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: This does not work for 3! Ping me as soon as you fix it!

Comment: @RGS Ping......

Comment: @S.S.Anne thanks! My pinger is broken

Answer (score 3):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 13 bytes

```
rimo{>]2.<}fe
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclLCoAgFAXQrdwVhPf5K4g2Ek0igyCJDGkgrt0607PmdIbnzqG9W2npiFeZFunGuodW49wEGgYWDh49qECCAmrQgBZ0oAcHyF9KfQ)

9 & 18 do work, but take a while because they're such large multiples. So I've taken them out of tests.

```
ri    # Read to int
mo    # Generate infinite list of multiples
{
 >]   # Largest digit
 2.<  # Less than 2
}fe   # Find the first element s.t.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>53</s> 49 bytes

<sup>turns out Max can cast chars to codes implicitly</sup>

I tried a recursive version, but it was longer. Can't think of a way to replace the loop with LINQ...

```cs
a=>{int r=a;while($"{r}".Max()>49)r+=a;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXogPEdgpuCrYK/xNt7aqBPIUi20Tr8ozMnFQNFaXqololPd/ECg1NOxNLzSJtoFRRaklpUZ5CkXXtf2uugCKgDg03DSNNTQTHGJljgswxReaYIXPMkTkWyBxDsNR/AA)

Comment: [I don't think LINQ will be better](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXogPEdgpuCrYK/xNt7VzzSnNTixKTclL1ghLz0lM1DEHyer6JFWGJOaWpmnpumUXFJRoVtnYqStUVWom1SnqOOTkalbZ2lTamBpqaWon/rbkCioB6NNw0jDQ1ERxjZI4JMscUmWOGzDFH5lggcwxBUv8B "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ExpiredData Well, that "can't think of a way" part was implicitly followed by "without doubling the byte count" :)

Comment: It's not that far off 16 bytes more.. maybe there's a way to golf it down.

Comment: Thanks for your C# submission! What is the LINQ thing?

Comment: @RGS: Language INtegrated Query (LINQ) is an series of APIs in .Net that allow you to handle collections with a query language. It has two syntaxes: 1. SQL-like syntax 2. Fluent syntax on the IEnumerable<T> interface. See here for the official documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/using-linq

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
0ô+_▒╙2<▼
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##DckxDkAwAIbR/buKpX@rLYm7iAUDsTiJRBP3MNrcpBcpb33rsM/TtoylmPeu@pyOfF62y@kpRVgcNZ5ApEEGCVnkUI08CiiiFvuXMR8) (Test cases `n=9` and `n=18` are excluded, since they time out.)

**Explanation:**

```python
0          # Start with 0
        ▼  # Do-while false with pop,
 ô         # using the following 6 commands:
  +        #  Add the (implicit) input-integer to the current value
   _       #  Duplicate it
    ▒      #  Convert it to a list of digits
     ╙     #  Pop and push the maximum digit of this list
      2<   #  And check if this max digit is smaller than 2 (thus 0 or 1)
           # (after the do-while, the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Question: if you answered 10 seconds ago, how come you already golfed it down from 10 to 9 bytes..? +1 for the mathgolf submission though

Comment: @RGS Yeah, could have just gone with the 9-byter, haha. I golfed it while adding the explanation (thus before posting) and realizing it could be shorter. EDIT: I've removed the strike-through 10.

Comment: If I golf my answer within the grace period then I never strike through because there's no way to recover the previous version.

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 52 bytes

```
func[n][i: 0 until[""= trim/with to""i: i + n"01"]i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnLCsIwEEDRvV9xma2ImT61oB/hNmQhfdCATiWk@PnRsz1pnspjnnw4LANl2W30FnwccOyW48uL3Mgpvs/fmFfyJvLPyBETpxJiKMuW5ue4YviKmoaWjp4L6lBFK7RGG7RFO7RHr1T/ci74T4qW8Yac7sKChVB@)

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 54 bytes

```
func[n][i: 0 until[parse to""i: i + n[any["0"|"1"]]]i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dck9CsMwDAbQvaf40FoKlvPXZughugoNJrGpoSjBSYZC7@5mfa/Eub7iLHpJI2o6bBJTySMcDtvzR9ZQtoh9ITox4wqTYF8hRz9iUtWsNS0lhukNg3g0aNGhx4A72IEZ7MENuAV34B48gB/wZzmnspZsO8RAtychwVTrHw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/instructions.md), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü◘ø⌠Δ>0↔å
```

Port of [my MathGolf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200033/52210). This is only my second Stax answer, so there might be a shorter alternative.

[Try it online](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=810800f4ff3e301d86&i=14) or [try it online unpacked (10 bytes)](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=0wx%2BcE%7CM1%3E&i=14).

**Explanation (of the unpacked version):**

```python
0             # Start at 0
 w            # While true without popping, by using everything else as block:
  x+          #  Add the input-integer
    c         #  Duplicate the top of the stack
     E        #  Convert it to a list of digits
      |M      #  Get the maximum of this list
        1>    #  And check that it's larger than 1
              # (after the while, the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: Cool Stax submission +1! Was stax created by someone from CG.SE?

Comment: @RGS [yep, by _recursive_](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14945/52210). :)

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about that meta question.

Comment: I'm not a really good Stax golfer. [Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82c76bac74873e4a&i=14)

Comment: @a'_' That unfortunately won't work for inputs that are already correct, like `1`, `10`, `11`,`100`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 50 bytes

```
procedure f(n)
i:=seq(n,n)&0=*(i--10)
return i
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY09DsIwDIX3nMLqgGKUSA4jUrkLaozkAQdMCuL0xVWH8ran7/3I1HRZHtYmrrMx3KJikPP44mfUpHig8Rgl50IYjPtsChJY61/lfhWNGMDFb7YveL1Ab3AiqA0@Jp2jJBjyZUh@ILiFN1CIduTG4Tr/Aw)

`seq(n,n)` generates an "infinite" (seq operator doesn’t work with large integers) sequence starting at `n` with step `n`

`&`is conjunction - Icon evaluates the next expression and if it fails, than backtracks to the expression to its left - so generates the next integer.

`i--10` finds the difference of the string representation of `i` with the string `10` - Icon automatically casts number to strings when an operation on strings is used.

`*(1--10)` finds the length of the difference of `i` and `10` (which is a string)

`0=*(1--10)` - if the length is `0`, the number is composed only of 1's and 0's.

Comment: Another uncommon language :D

Comment: @RGS Yes, it's true! Icon is an old language with some nice features, especially for its time. I'll write a short explanation of my code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>9</s></sup> 7 bytes

```
ḟoΛεd∫∞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9odXNr///huJ9vzpvOtWTiiKviiJ7///8y)

-2 bytes from Leo.

Comment: `M*N` would save you 1 byte over `m*⁰N`, but this can be even shorter by summing the input to itself repeatedly with `∫∞` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9odXNr///huJ9vzpvOtWTiiKviiJ7///8y "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: I thought of `¡+₁`, but `∫∞` is a lot smarter.

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 31 bytes

```
:i;1{).{2 base}:b~{`+}*~i%}do b
```

Worked for 2-15 wen I tried them out, didn't bother doing more. May post explanation later, just wanted to get a brute submission down.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlvaPTfKtPasFpTr9pIISmxOLXWKqmuOkG7VqsuU7U2JV8h6f9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
⟨:$2…⁻⟩+↺
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9nYWlh///in6g6JDLigKbigbvin6kr4oa6//8xMg)

```
		| implicit input, n
⟨     ⟩		| (1) monadic link:
 :$		| dup, and get decimal digits
   2…⁻		| remove all 1s and zeros
	↺	| if the result is truthy (non-empty)
       +	| add n and repeat from (1)
		| implicitly print result.
```

Times out on `n=9`...

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 10 bytes

```
1⟨bdĖ⟩#ebd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/3/DR/BVJKUemPZq/Ujk1KQUoYAgA)

Somewhat more interesting and also a lot faster; finds the first integer where: converting it to binary and interpreting as decimal digits are divisible by the input (and `ebd` converts it to the decimal form).

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

```
(For[x=#,Max@IntegerDigits@x>1,x+=#];x)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8V/DLb8ousJWWcc3scLBM68kNT21yCUzPbOk2KHCzlCnQttWOda6QlPtv6Y1F1dAUWZeSbSyrl1atHJsrJqCvoNCNZeRDpexDpeJDpepDpehARAbAjFQ0NCYq/b/fwA)

### Ignoring maximum iteration limits, 37 bytes

```
#//.a_?(Max@IntegerDigits@#>1&):>a+#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8V9ZX18vMd5ewzexwsEzryQ1PbXIJTM9s6TYQdnOUE3Tyi5RW1ntv6Y1F1dAUWZeSbSyrl1atHJsrJqCvoNCNZeRDpexDpeJDpepDpehARAbAjFQ0NCYq/b/fwA)

This will halt when the depth of 65536 is reached (i.e. if the result is larger than `65536 * (input)`).

Comment: `#//.a_?(Max@IntegerDigits@#>1&):>a+#&` could have worked with 37 bytes if it didn't have the built-in iteration limit of 65536.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is ok to use the 37 byte solution. Recursive Python solutions also have a recursion depth of 1000 and those are valid solutions.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
.Bf!%s.BTQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X88pTVG1WM8pJPD/f0NDAA)

`f`: Filter of all integers in increasing order, starting from an input of 1. Output the first matching input.

`.BT`: Convert the input to binary, as a string.

`s`: Convert the string to a base 10, as a integer.

`% ... Q`: Modulo the input

`!`: Boolean negation - returns true only if divisible.

`.B`: Convert the output of the filter back to a binary string and print it.

Comment: Thanks for your Pyth submission! +1

Comment: There is also a [much less efficient 10 byter](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P02xRjUkUDchxPr/f0NLAA).

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 50 bytes

```javascript
(x,i=1,g=v=>v.toString(2))=>g(i)/x%1?f(x,++i):g(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpLDoIwFEbhuatgYtIbfpFb5KUpjlyBQ@OAIK01pDVACLuvOD3f@bRLO3Wj/c4H51990CqIFVYxjFpUsySzv8@jdUZIItUYYem47vmqtyuOLZ3/JVweEhlOyFGgRIUanIIZLMEZ@ATOwQW4BFfgGnLTNH3uEu3HW9u9hYtUE3XeTX7ok8EboYUjovAD)

Comment: Thanks for your submission! Have you checked out [this JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200002/75323)? :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Roj](https://github.com/RojerGS/Roj), <del>178</del> <del>173</del> <del>171</del> <del>161</del> <del>160</del> <del>156</del> <del>153</del> <del>152</del> 141 bytes

Because I am completely new to Roj, there may still be potential golfs out here.

```
readint I;C=0;while 1 do
C=C+I;i=C;L=0<1;while i do
c=0;while c<=i/10 do
c=c+1
end;c=c-1;L=L and(i-10*c)<2;i=c
end;if L do
out C;halt
end
end
```

## Explanation

It's made primarily for me to find potential golfs.

Indented:

````
readint I; $ Take an input integer & save it into the variable I $
C = 0;     $ C: The counter that stores the current value $

while 1 do $ Forever: $

    C = C + I; $ Add the counter by the input $

    i = C; $ Copy the counter to a mutable variable $

    L = 0 < 1; $ Set the "Logic" variable to a truthy value $

               $ "0<1" is shorter than directly hard-coding "True", a 4-byte value $

    $ Check whether the input is made of 0 and 1 $

    $ This modifies the L variable $

    while i do $ Do the following "Scan" until we run out of digits $
        $ "Scan" over the input until we reach the end of the input $

        $ Current procedure: floor the value of the multiple / 10 $
        c = 0; $ Set the flooring result to the variable c $

        while c <= i / 10 do $ While the current counter is less $
                             $ than or equal to the multiple / 10 $
            c = c + 1        $ Increment the counter $
        end;
        c = c - 1;           $ Since we have one extra +1 to break $
                             $ out of the loop, we decrement the counter $

        L = L and (i - 10 * c)<2; $ Finally! Compare the currently-scanned $
                             $ number's equality with 1 or 0 $

        $ (i - 10 * c) Calculates i - 10 * (i // 10) $
        $ We already calculated (i // 10), $
        $ Hence the weird output expression $

        i = c                $ Divide the multiply by 10, floor that result $
    end;

    if L do         $ If this multiple is made of binary digits: $
        out C;      $ Output this multiple $
        halt        $ Stop the program $
    end
end
```
````

Comment: I might be looking at the 50 rep winner! Good job here

Comment: @RGS Have you made any other languages? I feel obliged to popularize them.

Comment: I haven't, no :p

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>68</s> 55 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
A	X =X + N
	X NOTANY(10)	:S(A)
	OUTPUT =X
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hMuRM0LBNkJBW8GPC8jy8w9x9IvUMDTQ5LQK1nDU5OL0Dw0BKgMq4XL1c/n/3wgA)

Adds `N` to `X`; if `X` contains any non-binary digits, repeat. Then print X.

Comment: This feels like a very exotic submission! Thanks :D

Comment: @RGS I like the challenge of golfing in a half-century old language.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
1BḌọɗ1#BḌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/Q6eGOnoe7e09ON1QGMf9bP2qYo6Brp/CoYa714XYuI4PD7Y@a1kT@/w8A)

A monadic link taking an integer \$n\$ and returning an integer.

Two bytes longer than [@JonathanAllan’s solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200043), but a different approach so I still thought worth posting.

### Explanation

```
1   ɗ1#   | Starting with 1, find the first integer for which the following is true, using n as the right argument:
 B        | - Convert to binary
  Ḍ       | - Convert from decimal digits to integer
   ọ      | - Number of times divisible by n
       B  | Convert to binary
        Ḍ | Convert from decimal digits to integer
```

## Another alternative [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
2*B€ḌọƇ⁸Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//MipC4oKs4biM4buNxofigbjhuKL/O@KAnCAtPiDigJ07w4cKMTDDh@KCrFn//zk)

Comment: (now at 2 bytes longer :P ) Thanks for posting the alternative solution!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 29 bytes

```perl6
{first /^[0|1]+$/,(1..*X*$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LCsIwEEX38xWzKNKHNpnWpnWh3yH4QrCBQqvSuik@fj2mdlIwEHK5Z@be3Mu2VqbpcaZxbZ66arsHiuNOvugQeWLuUxyH29A7BW/TnXvU/qcR@0skAtS3FuvqWnYmwcUGSUL6e4lgORoSMiaKiYScEUHBSgLhivl4gCTvEY0AKHEJ1kynDHJNw2w2lZBy2VbnzrbjSMVfk8VcPaQl0v3bXpZf)

Find the first multiple of the input that is only composed of ones and zeroes

Comment: Thanks for your Perl submission! Using regexs here, hun? :D

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>53</s> 48 bytes

```c
n,m;F(k){for(n=m=k;m>1;m=m%10>1?n+=k:m/10);n=n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/dbsIwDIXv8xQWU6VENSNmvyyku@MlWC@mlELUJUW07GKoz965dENjlizr2J@tYzfdOtf3EYNZyUqdyvogow22MiEjE2xISGf0GlNbvYQZaWWijabrb3x0H8diA8umLXx9u8uE8LGF8O6j/Kx9ocRJAMfQ9HF/bJt1DvbcGgdDzBHuEO4RHhAeEZ4QnhEWeJmTRiDiZJCYJEaJWWKYmCbGaYEw1393fkRnxLkOLw0uHFjQhssSGv@1qUs5@lKzK7nWuWIqTdU/s/sDXynlJClgmkFSvMUJ/r7mcoSVvAilzGhBdP03)

Explanation:

```c
int F(int k)
{
    int n = k;
    int m = k;

    for (; m > 1;)
    {
        if (m % 10 > 1)     // no solution if least significant digit nether 0 nor 1. Try next multiple of k.
        {
            n += k;
            m = n;
        }
        else                // if the least significant digit is 0 or 1 divide by ten
        {
            m /= 10;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

Edit: removed return

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
+⍣{∧/2>⍎¨⍕⍺}⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X/tR7@LqRx3L9Y3sHvX2HVrxqHfqo95dtY96V/xPe9Q2ASj2qG@qp/@jruZD640ftU0E8oKDnIFkiIdn8P@0QyuMFUwUTBXMFMwVLBQMDRQMzRWMDAA)

Straightforward algorithm: Repeat adding self until all digits are less than 2.

#### How it works

```apl
+⍣{∧/2>⍎¨⍕⍺}⍨  ⍝ Input: n
+⍣{        }⍨  ⍝ Repeat adding n with starting value of n, until ... is true:
       ⍎¨⍕⍺    ⍝   Extract the digits
   ∧/2>        ⍝   All of the digits are less than 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
_%U}f_Ä ¤
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=XyVVfWZfxCCk&input=Mw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
f=lambda k,n=0:max(`n`)!='1'and k+f(k,n+k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcyxCoMwFAXQ3a@4DsWEZEiyVciXFMFXbNqQepXgUL8@dT5w9vP4bAytpfiV9bkIimV04yo/NXPWfRz8IFxQTFIXmaJb2iqITFTh@6WCRfAaBg/v3DR2yAm83ftr6YC9Zh6gRVLU7Q8)

A recursive function. We terminate when the maximum character of the string representation is `1`. We can't quite use `'<2'` instead because zero would trigger it, and we don't have a good way not to start at zero.

The larger outputs run out of recursion depth, at least with the default value. We'll also eventually get another issue with huge inputs when Python 2's backticks string representation appends an `L` for "long" to numbers starting with `2**63`, which will always be the maximum.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
n=k=input()
while'1'<max(`n`):n+=k
print n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpLCoMwFAXQ@V2FZKLiJDf@ojR7sZSAwfYZJKV29elnfE58p3UXk19ruPuCsz/9TSmVxW0uSHymqsbfSpaXx/WsFlnqWRq3IR5BUiH51w1adOgxYITFBGqQoAFbsAN7cABH0IITzFe1/gA)

A program, using a pretty straightforward loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 38 bytes

```hs
f x=filter(all(<'2').show)[x,x+x..]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwjYtM6cktUgjMSdHw0bdSF1Trzgjv1wzukKnQrtCTy9WUdHgf25iZp5tbmKBb7xGQVFmXommSpqNil20kZ6eoUHsfwA)

### Explanation

We make all the multiples of `x` with `[x,x+x..]`, filter them to contain only digits smaller than two `filter(all(<'2').show)` and then take the first one `!!0`

Comment: Really cool solution +1 Thanks for it.

Comment: You may want to compare with [mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200015/56725).

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 38 bytes

```julia
f(k,n=k)="10"⊇repr(n) ? n : f(k,n+k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P00jWyfPNlvTVsnQQOlRV3tRakGRRp6mgr1CnoKVAlhWO1vzf0FRZl6JRpqGoamm5n8A)

Comment: It is fairly annoying that you need spaces around `?:`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>16</s> 12 bytes

```
TMXa<2a+:@ga
```

-4 bytes from Dlosc (removed unnecessary function)

The same general approach that most other answers are using: Loop until we reach a multiple that can also be a binary number. Takes very long for numbers \$>17\$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/xDci0cYoUdvKIT3x////hiYA)

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 27 bytes

```
x:a
MN({a%x?0a}MTB,2**a)RM0
```

Converts all numbers till \$2^n\$ to binary and checks divisibility. Then removes all the 0's and gets the minimum. Takes very long for numbers \$>14\$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P@/wiqRy9dPozpRtcLeILHWN8RJx0hLK1EzyNfg////ZgA)

Comment: Nice use of `@g`! [-4 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/xDci0cYoUdvKIT3x////hiYA) because `UQ` isn't necessary and neither are the parentheses.

Comment: For the second version, you can use `FI`lter instead of map-to-zero-and-remove-zeros.

Comment: why's it say that `FI` is not a unary operator? https://tio.run/##K8gs@P@/wiqRy9dPw80zxEnHSEsrUTPI1@D///9mAA

Comment: Because [I added unary `FI` just yesterday.](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip/commit/82edcd8d2c1a4bcf20e35950acc8ce40b63a0c83). Unfortunately, TIO isn't getting updates at the moment, so it's unclear when or whether new features will be available there. :( In the meantime, you can either run Pip from command-line or use `_FI` on TIO.

Comment: Cool, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 74 bytes

```powershell
param($x)for(){$n=iex ([convert]::tostring(++$i,2));if(!($n%$x)){$n;exit}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCoAgEADArxQYrNSpbkUviQ4Say2YxiolRG/fau5zhAs5buicyGHY7KCytoFB38qPhLmAaQn@RE5z36cQE5Nfoa4VNa3WA1koQfnqW/8YMFN6HhHpXg)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 41 bytes

```powershell
for(;++$n%"$args"-or$n-match'[2-9]'){}
$n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFba4MwFH7Przh06VSqYOx6YxTK9tSnDtq3UoZ16WVo4qKyDedvt7mtel78zndLiDn/pqK40DRt8QmWULcnLtzn0Qiz4QDH4lwMAi4wC7K4TC7OPgoWB8erG4RZ2yC0cpHvRuADCT2JxgoRouCTJjU7uetTo2s8MwZtnhuseRLe7YRov4aRjRph3AsTe5TNTHpnkKktNtvMSia20JsticLuvvLzv6AH2HEOKWdnkA8Du/VGUr5rsnY8TZF5n1NZD/5gCDUCOZhV2ZEKHzD9yWlS0g/52PjdaIIWVVrC8lH@AmvUwv5t@1oVJc82x0@ZOaxMl5ptlSS0KFSJTQf0qyu/@9Ysr0rl6tWqcV6uLBa/kMnoNU@p0zVpT4Oa9gY)

---

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 41 bytes

```powershell
for(;++$n%"$args"-or$n-replace'0|1'){}
$n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFbT4MwFH7vrziZnUAGCWXuYsySRZ/2NJPtzRjDsJszpcUCUbPx27E3gfPCd75bm1KIbyrLD8pYi4@wgkt7FNJ/mEwwH49wKk/lKBIS80jSgqUZ9eIr8YJLgzBvG4TWPgr9BEIgcaDQVCNCNLwzpGFnnT63usELazDmpcWGJ3FnJ8T4DUxc1ArTQZi4o1xmNjiDzF2x3RZOsrF7s7mSJO7vqz7/C7qBvRDABD@BehjYb7aKCn2bdRMYiiyHnM4GcIUxXBCowbzOD1SGgOlPQbOKvqvHxm9Wk7SsWQWrW/ULnNEIL8@7p7qsRL49fKrM69p26dnVWUbLUpe4dES/@vLOt@FFXWnXoFaP93jmqfyFXEXPBaNe32Q8DWraPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 17 bytes

```
{(|/1<10\)(x+)/x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxVj81qwzAQhO/7FD70YFOKduT4J1bpi7iG9GIoDQQSQx3S9Nm7Wq3cVmA0zLc7I8/DrfxyeAa/VuX6WLn1TrQMt4fx+n0e5mINh9NHKA/z2/sxrOEaztV0p2X0ATzJXQcAUezEUKcx0kaiqotIh/qoxHPLuI84nalwl+PpUzjYloGQYuE1Jpn1FgSts9lma0KrBUl3akPb0P/W8Z+++AqL9Jz/QK4kyZEvnl4KMNV6A7RLBlNjpDXC1BkC9aaY9kbTIbBtAQkQfN4Xs94SkHvibLNVoM3Jortsy3j/r0egFccsz/nN8pn8AShcbXk=)

Sets up a straightforward while-over, seeded with `x`. Runs until `(|/1<10\)` returns `0` when executed on the result.

- `(...)(x+)/x` generate the next multiple of the original input, starting with the initial input
- `(|/1<10\)(...)/x` the condition tested after each iteration

  - `10\` convert to digits
  - `|/1<` check if any digit is larger than 1

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
(G⁻;+
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT0oRyVFMiU4MSVCQiUzQiUyQiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTcmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
(G⁻;+  # Implicit input
(  ;   # While loop
 G     # (condition)  Maximum of (implicit cast to digits of) top of stack
  ⁻    #              Decrement (i.e. not equal to one)
    +  # (body)  Add the input to the top of stack
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 38 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.75 bytes

```
{:₀F|+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyI9IiwiIiwiezrigoBGfCsiLCIiLCIzIl0=)

Ports Thunno 2 but with fractional bytes.

### Explained

```
{:₀F|+­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
{   |   # ‎⁡While:
  ₀F    # ‎⁢  The numbers from 10 removed from
 :      # ‎⁣  A copy of the top of a stack is not empty
    |   # ‎⁤Do:
     +  # ‎⁢⁡  Add the input to the top of the stack 

 Created with the help of Luminespire at https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 230 bytes

```
def f(n):
 s="1"
 while 2>1:
  if int(s)%n==0:
   return s
  if "0" in s:
   for j in range(0,len(s)):
    if s[j]=="0":
     q=j
   t=s[:q]
   for k in range(q,len(s)):
    t=t+str(1-int(s[k]))
   s=t
  else:
   s=str(10**len(s))
```

Comment: This seems a bit long to me, any suggestions that don't involve using lambdas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 67 bytes

Port of [@ovs's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200011/110802) in Scala.

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU/BisIwEL3vVzz2oAmpkva0LbrgcWE9iSfxEDWVaDpdkiiK9NtrGl0G3vBm5r2Z8XtlVd/uTnofsFSG8PgADrpGEwlT7ugrLJxT980qOEPHLa@wJhMwT5PAVVnQpdlp52ONFbhQMBYlhxBguXzz/CsVfo0PLC@zQma5lDw51K0DixaYTf6d@Nsc@ItLg6XUF/iMIVAPjL/EXcSuHw6u2bn6oZDRgHPJUzJx9luORjQN7euBaaNus3Ex5gRtvR5kGYkz77v@CQ)

```scala
def f(k:Int,n:Int=0):Int=if(n>0&&n.toString.max<'2')n else f(k,n+k)
```